# How do I find out my PYTHONPATH using Python?

Tags: python, python-module, pythonpath

How do I find out which directories are listed in my system’s `PYTHONPATH` variable, from within a Python script (or the interactive shell)?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do, but if you want to know which folders are used to search for modules being imported you should not rely on `PYTHONPATH`. Use `sys.path` for that.

Comment: By simple experiment, I found Vanuan's answer below (printing sys.path) just prints PYTHONPATH. This works after we alter the value using add_path(new_path) which adds to PYTHONPATH.

Comment: The title of this post and the body ask two different questions. `sys.path` is "A list of strings that specifies the search path for modules" - https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path. PYTHONPATH is an environment variable that effects this list. By any reasonable definition `sys.path` is your "python path".

Comment: Don't forget about `python -m site`.

Answer (score 294, accepted):

`sys.path` might include items that aren't specifically in your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. To query the variable directly, use:

```
import os
try:
    user_paths = os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)
except KeyError:
    user_paths = []
```

Comment: (or, more generically  ...split(os.sep) ).   Can't figure out why you're not getting the love, Mark.  Your reply is technically more accurate than Paul D Waite's own reply to his question ????

Comment: Ah, excellent. Thanks guys, I suspected I was doing something wrong. I’ve deleted my wrong answer; Mark, if you could edit your answer to include the os.sep bit, the points will rightfully be yours.

Comment: os.sep is incorrect, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499019/how-to-get-the-path-separator-in-python

Comment: And that problem with the separator is probably why I wasn't getting the love. Thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: And if receive a KeyError, does it means that PYTHONPATH is not defined in my system? Is that a problem? Thanks

Comment: @glarrin, correct - KeyError means that PYTHONPATH is not defined. It won't be a problem because there's already default paths set up, see `sys.path`.

Comment: I'm not seeing an answer here to solve the `PYTHONPATH` `KeyError` error. Do I need to define `PYTHONPATH` in relation to `sys.path`?

Comment: @MikeiLL you're right, I've edited the answer to include that. If there's no `PYTHONPATH` then the user didn't specify one and an empty list is the proper result. If you're more interested in the list that includes the defaults use `sys.path` instead.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. You might even want to add `print user_paths` to the code. Also I found this link to be enlightening as far as PYTHONPATH: http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/understanding-imports-and-pythonpath

Answer (score 825):

You would probably also want this:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Or as a one liner from the terminal:

```
python -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"
```

---

**Caveat**: If you have multiple versions of Python installed you should use a corresponding command `python2` or `python3`.

Comment: Same. Linux aaa.com 2.6.18-4-686-bigmem #1 SMP Wed Jun 6 09:41:07 UTC 2007 i686 GNU/Linux ... Debian Sarge

Comment: This is the platform- and environment- independent way to get the current runtime's python path.

Comment: This answer was much more helpful for my situation than the accepted answer.  I know what my environment variables is.  I needed to know where python decided to point besides my environment variable.

Comment: I find it easier to use the following, since it makes it clear if the empty string (`''`) is in the path: `python -c "import sys, pprint; pprint.pprint(sys.path)"` (
And I found this answer more helpful, too; the title of the question mislead me into thinking it was about the actual path python was using, rather than the contents of the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.)

Comment: I used `sys.path[0]` to get the "deffault" path where a local file ist stored. Oterwise I get an array with lots of paths. e.g `fiel=open(MyLogfile.log, 'w')`

Comment: For Python 3: python3 -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"

Comment: Slightly Cleaner:
import sys
for p in sys.path:
    print(p)

Comment: @juggler Nope, "for" loops are not cleaner than functional style. It's a matter of preference and programming paradigm.

Comment: @Vanuan  -I meant that the output was cleaner.  from what I could tell..  maybe the output from your one-liner is also as clean?  you're right that it's a matter of preference :-) peace :-)

Comment: @mirceamironenco's solution can be adapted to support Linux/Unix path appending via: `export PYTHONPATH="python -c \"import sys; print(':'.join(sys.path))\""`

Answer (score 20):

Can't seem to edit the other answer.  Has a minor error in that it is Windows-only.  The more generic solution is to use os.pathsep as below:

sys.path might include items that aren't specifically in your PYTHONPATH environment variable. To query the variable directly, use:

```
import os
os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH', '').split(os.pathsep)
```

Comment: For future readers: `os.sep` returns the directory separator for the operating system, e.g.  `/`. The separator used in the Python path is different, and returned by `os.pathsep` as shown in the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. I always get them mixed up when writing code by hand.

Answer (score 10):

PYTHONPATH is an environment variable whose value is a list of directories. Once set, it is used by Python to search for imported modules, along with other std. and 3rd-party library directories listed in Python's "sys.path".

As any other environment variables, you can either export it in shell or in ~/.bashrc, see [here](https://bic-berkeley.github.io/psych-214-fall-2016/using_pythonpath.html). 
You can query os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] for its value in Python as shown below:

```
$ python3 -c "import os, sys; print(os.environ['PYTHONPATH']); print(sys.path) if 'PYTHONPATH' in sorted(os.environ) else print('PYTHONPATH is not defined')"
```

IF defined in shell as

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/Documents/DjangoTutorial/mysite
```

THEN result =>

```
/home/Documents/DjangoTutorial/mysite
['', '/home/Documents/DjangoTutorial/mysite', '/usr/local/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

ELSE result =>

```
PYTHONPATH is not defined
```

To set PYTHONPATH to multiple paths, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39682688/how-to-set-pythonpath-to-multiple-folders).

Note that one can add or delete a search path via sys.path.insert(), del or remove() at run-time, but NOT through os.environ[].
Example:

```
>>> os.environ['PYTHONPATH']="$HOME/Documents/DjangoTutorial/mysite"
>>> 'PYTHONPATH' in sorted(os.environ)
True
>>> sys.path // but Not there
['', '/usr/local/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages']

>>> sys.path.insert(0,os.environ['PYTHONPATH'])
>>> sys.path // It's there
['$HOME/Documents/DjangoTutorial/mysite', '', '/usr/local/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
>>>
```

In summary, PYTHONPATH is one way of specifying the Python search path(s) for imported modules in sys.path. You can also apply list operations directly to sys.path without the aid of PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Being that you're using brackets and not `.get()`, if PYTHONPATH is not defined, you'll simply get a traceback error and neither the path nor "PYTHONPATH is not defined" are printed. Replace it with `print(os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH'));` and the output will default to `None` instead of failing.

Answer (score 8):

Works in windows 10, essentially identical to vanuan's answer, but cleaner (taken from somewhere, can't remember where..):

```
import sys
for p in sys.path:
    print(p)
```

Comment: This one line does the same job `import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))`

Answer (score 4):

```
import subprocess
python_path = subprocess.check_output("which python", shell=True).strip()
python_path = python_path.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: This is not relevant to the question; `PYTHONPATH` is **not** "where Python lives", but an environment variable with additional paths to search for modules.

Answer (score 1):

Python tells me where it lives when it gives me an error message :)

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'PYTHONPATH'
>>>
```

Comment: This is not relevant to the question; `PYTHONPATH` is **not** "where Python lives", but an environment variable with additional paths to search for modules.

Answer (score 0):

If using conda, you can get the env prefix using `os.environ["CONDA_PREFIX"]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
for a in sys.path:
    a = a.replace('\\\\','\\')
    print(a)
```

It will give all the paths ready for place in the Windows.

Comment: Calling `.replace` on a string *does not modify the string*, but instead creates a *new* one which is ignored in this code. Not that it matters, because there is no good reason to unescape the backslashes anyway. Path strings from `sys.path` are usable on that system as is.

Answer (score -2):

Use the command,

```sh
$ which python
```

remember to enter this in the correct environment so use:

```sh
$ conda activate <env>
```

or

```sh
$ mamba activate <env>
```

If you do not have a conda environment, `$ which python` or `$ which python3` would do just fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is not relevant to the question; `PYTHONPATH` is **not** "where Python lives", but an environment variable with additional paths to search for modules.