# How to get the PATH environment-variable separator in Python?

Tags: python, operating-system, environment-variables

When multiple directories need to be concatenated, as in an executable search path, there is an os-dependent separator character.  For Windows it's `';'`, for Linux it's `':'`.  Is there a way in Python to get which character to split on?

In the discussions to this question [How do I find out my python path using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489599/how-do-i-find-out-my-python-path-using-python) , it is suggested that `os.sep` will do it. That answer is wrong, since it is the separator for components of a directory or filename and equates to `'\\'` or `'/'`.

Answer (score 237, accepted):

[`os.pathsep`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.pathsep)

Comment: If, like me, you didn't read the body of this question and just went by the title, you'll think this is the character that separates elements of a **filesystem path** (forward slash on Linux and MacOSX, backslash on Windows).  It's not, it the character that separates elements of a shell **PATH** that is used to locate executable commands.  `os.sep` or `os.path.sep` is what you need for filesystem paths.

Comment: `os.pathsep` is `:` or `;` while `os.path.sep` is `\\ ` or `/` - sometimes the names in Python strike me as shockingly poorly chosen. That `.` makes way too big of a difference.

Comment: @Perry i edited the question. hopefully my edit clears up the confusion (i indicated that this question is asking about the "PATH environment variable" instead of a "filesystem path").

Comment: So there are `os.sep` and `os.path.sep`, which are equal, as well as `os.pathsep` and `os.path.pathsep` which are also equal. Why would they do this?

Answer (score 32):

It is os.pathsep

Answer (score 17):

OK, so there are:

- `os.pathsep` that is `;` and which is a separator in the `PATH` environment variable;
- `os.path.sep` that is `/` in Unix/Linux and `\` in Windows, which is a separator between path components.

The similarity is a source of confusion.

Answer (score 14):

Making it a little more explicit (For python newbies like me)

```
import os
print(os.pathsep)
```

Answer (score -5):

This is a sample path for your working directory/specific folder -

```
 import os
 my = os.pathsep+ "testImages" + os.pathsep + "imageHidden.png"
 print(my)
```

Output for Linux-

`:testImages:imageHidden.png`

Output for Windows-

`;testImages;imageHidden.png`