# python subprocess Popen environment PATH?

Tags: python, path, subprocess, environment, popen

Suppose there's an executable and a Python script to launch it, and they're located in 'sibling' subdirectories, e.g.

```
/tmp/subdir1/myexecutable
/tmp/subdir2/myscript.py
```

If in `/tmp` and running `python subdir2/myscript.py` with a relative path to executable

```
# myscript.py
from subprocess import Popen
proc = Popen(["../subdir1/myexecutable"])
```

It makes `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

How does the Python search for the executable? Does it use the current working directory and/or location of the script? Does it use PATH and/or PYTHONPATH? Can you change where and how `subprocess.Popen` searches for the executable? Are commands, absolute and relative paths for executables treated differently? Are there differences between Linux and Windows? What does `shell=True` or `shell=False` influence?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Relative paths (paths containing slashes) never get checked in any `PATH`, no matter what you do. They are relative to the *current working directory* only.  If you need to resolve relative paths, you will have to search through the `PATH` manually.

If you want to run a program *relative to the location of the Python script*, use `__file__` and go from there to find the absolute path of the program, and then use the absolute path in `Popen`.

### Searching in the current process' environment variable `PATH`

There is [an issue in the Python bug tracker](http://bugs.python.org/issue8557) about how Python deals with bare commands (no slashes).  Basically, on Unix/Mac [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) behaves like `os.execvp` when the argument `env=None` (some unexpected behavior has been observed and noted at the end):

> On POSIX, the class uses `os.execvp()`-like behavior to execute the child program.

This is actually true for both `shell=False` and `shell=True`, provided `env=None`.  What this behavior means is explained in the documentation of the function [`os.execvp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execvp):

> The variants which include a “p” near the end (`execlp()`, `execlpe()`, `execvp()`, and `execvpe()`) will use the `PATH` environment variable to locate the program *file*. When the environment is being replaced (using one of the `exec*e` variants, discussed in the next paragraph), the new environment is used as the source of the `PATH` variable.

> For `execle()`, `execlpe()`, `execve()`, and `execvpe()` (note that these all end in “e”), the *env* parameter must be a mapping which is used to define the environment variables for the new process (these are used instead of the current process’ environment); the functions `execl()`, `execlp()`, `execv()`, and `execvp()` all cause the new process to inherit the environment of the current process.

The second quoted paragraph implies that `execvp` will use the current process' environment variables.  Combined with the first quoted paragraph, we deduce that `execvp` will use the value of the environment variable `PATH` from the environment of the current process.  This means that `Popen` looks at the value of `PATH` *as it was when Python launched* (the Python that runs the `Popen` instantiation) and no amount of changing `os.environ` will help you fix that.

Also, on Windows with `shell=False`, `Popen` pays no attention to `PATH` at all, and will only look in relative to the current working directory.

### What `shell=True` does

What happens if we pass `shell=True` to `Popen`? In that case, [`Popen` simply calls the shell](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

> The *shell* argument (which defaults to `False`) specifies whether to use the shell as the program to execute.

> That is to say, `Popen` does the equivalent of:
>
> ```sh
> Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', args[0], args[1], ...])
> ```

In other words, with `shell=True` Python will directly execute `/bin/sh`, without any searching (passing the argument `executable` to `Popen` can change this, and it seems that if it is a string without slashes, then it will be interpreted by Python as the shell program's name to search for in the value of `PATH` from the environment of the current process, i.e., as it searches for programs in the case `shell=False` described above).

In turn, `/bin/sh` (or our shell `executable`) will look for the program we want to run in its own environment's `PATH`, which is the same as the `PATH` of the Python (current process), as deduced from the code after the phrase "That is to say..." above (because that call has `shell=False`, so it is the case already discussed earlier).  Therefore, the `execvp`-like behavior is what we get with both `shell=True` and `shell=False`, as long as `env=None`.

### Passing `env` to `Popen`

So what happens if we pass `env=dict(PATH=...)` to `Popen` (thus defining an environment variable `PATH` in the environment of the program that will be run by `Popen`)?

In this case, the new environment is used to search for the program to execute. Quoting the documentation of `Popen`:

> If *env* is not `None`, it must be a mapping that defines the environment variables for the new process; these are used instead of the default behavior of inheriting the current process’ environment.

Combined with the above observations, and from experiments using `Popen`, this means that `Popen` in this case behaves like the function [`os.execvpe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execvpe).  If `shell=False`, Python searches for the given program in the newly defined `PATH`. As already discussed above for `shell=True`, in that case the program is either `/bin/sh`, or, if a program name is given with the argument `executable`, then this alternative (shell) program is searched for in the newly defined `PATH`.

In addition, if `shell=True`, then *inside the shell* the search path that the shell will use to find the program given in `args` is the value of `PATH` passed to `Popen` via `env`.

So with `env != None`, `Popen` searches in the value of the key `PATH` of `env` (if a key `PATH` is present in `env`).

### Propagating environment variables other than `PATH` as arguments

There is a caveat about environment variables other than `PATH`: if the values of those variables are needed in the command (e.g., as command-line arguments to the program being run), then even if these are present in the `env` given to `Popen`, they will not get interpreted without `shell=True`.
This is easily avoided without changing `shell=True`: insert those value directly in the `list` argument `args` that is given to `Popen`.  (Also, if these values come from Python's own environment, the method `os.environ.get` can be used to get their values).

### Using `/usr/bin/env`

If you JUST need path evaluation and don't really want to run your command line through a shell, and are on UNIX, I advise using `env` instead of `shell=True`, as in

```py
path = '/dir1:/dir2'
subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/env', '-P', path, 'progtorun', other, args], ...)
```

This lets you pass a different `PATH` to the [`env`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Env) process (using the option `-P`), which will use it to find the program.  It also avoids issues with shell metacharacters and potential security issues with passing arguments through the shell.  Obviously, on Windows (pretty much the only platform without a `/usr/bin/env`) you will need to do something different.

### About `shell=True`

Quoting the `Popen` documentation:

> If *shell* is `True`, it is recommended to pass `args` as a string rather than as a sequence.

> **Note:** Read the [Security Considerations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations) section before using `shell=True`.

### Unexpected observations

The following behavior was observed:

- This call raises `FileNotFoundError`, as expected:

  ```py
  subprocess.call(['sh'], shell=False, env=dict(PATH=''))
  ```
- This call finds `sh`, which is unexpected:

  ```py
  subprocess.call(['sh'], shell=False, env=dict(FOO=''))
  ```

  Typing `echo $PATH` inside the shell that this opens reveals that the `PATH` value is not empty, and also different from the value of `PATH` in the environment of Python.  So it seems that `PATH` was indeed not inherited from Python (as expected in the presence of `env != None`), but still, it the `PATH` is nonempty. Unknown why this is the case.
- This call raises `FileNotFoundError`, as expected:

  ```py
  subprocess.call(['tree'], shell=False, env=dict(FOO=''))
  ```
- This finds `tree`, as expected:

  ```py
  subprocess.call(['tree'], shell=False, env=None)
  ```

Comment: A simple way that should work on Windows too is to explicitly give `os.environ['PATH']` as the argument `env` to `subprocess.Popen`, as done here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4453495/1959808 and there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20669704/1959808.

Comment: the `/usr/bin/env` trick does not work, at least for system commands like `useradd` and at least at CentOS (with empty PATH from cron): `/usr/bin/env: groupadd: No such file or directory`

Comment: If PATH is empty, that's not surprising.  AFAIK, unlike the shell, /usr/bin/env doesn't have a default PATH it falls back on.  Honestly, I wouldn't recommend relying on the shell's default PATH anyway; if you're writing cron jobs, just write out the full paths to your binaries or set a PATH yourself.

Comment: I have a `subprocess.Popen` that does appear to search the path with `shell=False`. What is ineffective, however, is augmenting the path to include the location of the executable using `sys.path.append` - I found that it only works if `%PATH%` contains the path to the executable before the Python program is launched.

Comment: I get usr/bin/env: invalid option -- 'P', I don't see a P option in env help

Answer (score 16):

You appear to be a little confused about the nature of `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH`.

`PATH` is an environment variable that tells the OS shell where to search for executables.

`PYTHONPATH` is an environment variable that tells the Python interpreter where to search for modules to import. It has nothing to do with `subprocess` finding executable files.

Due to the differences in the underlying implementation, `subprocess.Popen` will only search the path by default on non-Windows systems (Windows has some system directories it always searches, but that's distinct from `PATH` processing). The only reliable cross-platform way to scan the path is by passing `shell=True` to the subprocess call, but that has its own issues (as detailed in the [`Popen` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess#subprocess.Popen))

However, it appears your main problem is that you are passing a path fragment to `Popen` rather than a simple file name. As soon as you have a directory separator in there, you're going to disable the `PATH` search, even on a non-Windows platform (e.g. see the Linux documentation for the [exec family of functions](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/exec.3.html)).

Comment: This doesn't match up with the Python docs. [The Popen docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) state that the program is executed via `os.execvp` -- and that call DOES take into account the PATH environment variable.  Also, if you JUST need path evaluation, I advise using `env` instead of `shell=True`, as in `Popen(['/usr/bin/env', 'progtorun', other, args], ...)`.  This avoids issues with shell metacharacters and potential security issues with passing arguments through the shell.

Comment: Those are both *NIX specific though - they don't work on Windows, so I don't like recommending them as workarounds for a nominally cross-platform module. You're correct that my answer is incorrect as written though - will edit accordingly.

Comment: Updated to make it clear that not searching PATH by default is a Windows-only thing, but also to point out the real problem (a directory separator in the command to be executed).

Comment: A small alteration.  `subprocess.Popen`  will pick up executables in `C:\Windows\System32` which (and I had fun figuring this out) if you're running 32-bit python on a 64-bit Windows is actually `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`

Comment: @JohnOxley I've tweaked the answer to mention that, but are you aware of any good reference links for that? Maybe on MSDN somewhere?

Comment: Personally, I've had no problem with windows and paths... no idea why.   Totally finds "nosetests" in the path, for example on our Jenkins virtualenv windows instances.

Answer (score 2):

A relative path in subprocess.Popen acts relative to the current working directory, not the elements of the systems PATH.  If you run `python subdir2/some_script.py` from `/dir` then the expected executable location (passed to Popen) will be `/dir/../subdir1/some_executable`, a.k.a `/subdir1/some_executable` not `/dir/subdir1/some_executable`.

If you would definitely like to use relative paths from a scripts own directory to a particular executable the best option would be to first construct an absolute path from the directory portion of the `__file__` global variable.

```
#/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join
path = abspath(join(dirname(__file__), '../subdir1/some_executable'))
spam, eggs = Popen(path, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).communicate()
```

Comment: Uh, what? `subdir2/some_script.py` relative to `/dir` is simply `/dir/subdir2/some_script.py`

Comment: The python script at `subdir2/some_script.py` executes `Popen` with an executable path of `../subdir1/some_executable`. It is that executable path that is resolved relative to the current working director `/dir`, resulting in `/dir/../subdir1/some_executable`.

See Walter's answer, which says the same thing in different ways. I could have worded my answer better. Cheers!

edit: looks like I had a typo in my answer too, using `subdir2` in the executable path where I meant `subdir1`.

Answer (score 0):

The pythonpath is set to the path from where the python interpreter is executed. So, in second case of your example, the path is set to /dir and not /dir/subdir2
That's why you get an error.

Comment: I meant to say that the directory from which python is executed, that directory is added to pythonpath. Here in the 2nd case, /dir is added, and not /dir/subdir2. So, you can either change your code to reflect the changes (one way can be to add /dir/subdir2 to os.path in your code) or launch python from the appropriate directory.