# How to use subprocess.call without shell=True

Tags: python, windows

[The documents](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) recommend against using `subprocess.call` with `shell=True`, however when I try to do something as simple as

```
call(['convert'])
```

I get an error:

> Must specify a file system

When I run the same command via cmd.exe, I get

```
C:\Users\Mark>convert
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.3-6 2011-11-10 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
...
```

etc., i.e., it actually runs.

So what's `call` doing? Why is it looking for a file?

Does it require a full path to the .exe? If so, I'd prefer not to do that, as I don't know where all the .exes are located.

---

Just tried it with the full file path to a program (`call(['C:/imagemagick/convert.exe'])`) and that works. But the question still stands...how do you do it without the full path? Just have it execute from working directory?

Comment: Not an expert at Windows, but one guess is try 'dir.exe'

Comment: @RSamuelKlatchko: Same error. File extension can usually be omitted for .exes on windows.

Comment: You're using a Python interpreter installed on Windows, not a Python interpreter inside Cygwin or a similar environment, right?

Comment: @gotgenes: \*shifty eyes\* Was running it through my IDE. ... Nah, just tried through the cmd shell (`> python calltest.py`), and it does the exact same thing as when I run it through the IDE, which just runs normal Python (not Cygwin).

Comment: @RSamuelKlatchko `dir` is a shell built-in on Windows, not a program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coincidently I had this exact issue with the exact executable. This thread helped me point out the cause.

It seems to me that:

```py
subprocess.call([shutil.which("convert")])
```

Is an easy and portable solution to this problem.

Answer (score 4):

I believe `dir` is a builtin function of cmd.com, not a standalone program. You will need shell=True or a program that provides similar functionality to `dir` (like the ls.exe program in unixtools).

UPDATE FOR YOUR EDIT: What you're dealing with sounds exactly like a known issue/bug described here: http://bugs.python.org/issue8557 and here [python subprocess Popen environment PATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658622/python-subprocess-popen-environment-path)

It seems the behaviour of subprocess.call when `shell=False` is quite odd under win32. It seems like at a minimum you need to use `convert.exe` not `convert` and you need to [search `PATH` yourself](http://bugs.python.org/issue8557#msg105867).

Comment: Ah! Okay. That was a bad example then. I actually want to use ImageMagick's `convert`, which is an *actual* exe. Having the same problem there.

Comment: re:your update: That bug sounds exactly like the issue I'm having. Nice to see the second I dive back into Python I get slapped with a library bug! Haha! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is better understood by trying `dir.exe` in a shell:

```
C:\Users\lvc>dir.exe
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 4B8C-511A

 Directory of C:\Users\lvc

File Not Found
```

This means that `dir` is not an executable anywhere in your `%PATH%` - rather, it is a command that the shell knows how to do without looking up a program for it. That means it will never, by definition, work with `shell=False`.

Comment: Interesting. Never tried running it with the .exe before. If I had edited my environment variables to include whatever directory dir.exe is in, it would work?

Comment: @Mark you'll find that including `dir`s directory in `%PATH%` might be difficult, since the issue isn't that it isn't there already with the shell doing magic to be able to find it anyway. The issue is that `dir` isn't implemented by a standalone `.exe` - there *is no* `dir.exe` to include.

Comment: @lvc: Oooh. Okay. I was just using `dir.exe` as a [bad] example anyway.. I'm really using ImageMagick's convert, which *is* somewhere on my path. Running that via python (`call(['convert'])`) says "Must specify a file system", but via cmd actually runs the program.

Comment: @Mark I can't reproduce this with `convert` - it runs fine, and exits with `4`. You may wish to check `os.environ['PATH']` to make sure the path python is seeing agrees with the one cmd is seeing.

Comment: Is the command `dir.exe` being interpreted as `dir .exe` or something (so that the `dir` command shows `File Not Found` due to the absence of a `.exe` file)? Otherwise I'd expect to see `'dir.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I believe so, yes. Someone else had previously commented that that was the case, but that appears to have been deleted.