# Python subprocess.Popen Not finding Executable

Tags: python

I'm having issues with Python finding an available Executable on my Linux machine.  My default PATH includes this Executable (svnlook) but when I run the python script the below function fails to find executable.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
def command_output(cmd):
    child  = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = child.communicate()[0]
    return output, child.returncode


def get_author():
    cmd = "svnlook author %s %s %s" % (svn_opt, svn_txn, svn_repo)
    author, return_code = command_output(cmd)

    return author.strip()
```

Error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/app/csvn/data/repositories/repo/hooks/pre-commit", line 82, in <module>
    author = get_author()
  File "/home/user/app/csvn/data/repositories/repo/hooks/pre-commit", line 53, in get_author
    author, return_code = command_output(cmd)
  File "/home/user/app/csvn/data/repositories/repo/hooks/pre-commit", line 36, in command_output
    child  = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/home/user/app/activepython-2.7.2.5_x86_64/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/home/user/app/activepython-2.7.2.5_x86_64/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1228, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: You are not finding an _executable_ not a process.

Comment: @hcwhsa added traceback, any ideas?

Comment: Try printing your `sys.path` from Python and see if the path is passed to Python correctly. In addition try running the `svnlook` with it's full path and see if it resolves the issue.
I'd also make sure that `svnlook` is not an alias - which is bash internal and can't be passed to a running program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to provide the full path to the executable,  e.g. `/usr/bin/svnlook` or `/usr/local/bin/svnlook` instead of just `svnlook`.

See [this answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5659249/180174) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it from the console. Make sure the permissions/executability is correct. Try os.system().