# Python work with parent shell environment

Tags: python, linux, shell

Is it possible to create a shell object and manipulate it without losing it's data after command execution?

```
from subprocess import *
sh.Popen('/bin/bash', stdout=PIPE)
sh.communicate('source /path/to/file/env.sh')
print os.getenv('ENV_VAR1')
```

`ENV_VAR1` should be available after sourcing `/path/to/file/env.sh` but it's not.
This part of code is not working as expected, how can I make it work?

Here is another try which is not working as well

```
os.system('source env.sh; echo $ENV_VAR1') #Prints out correct value
os.system('echo $ENV_VAR1') #Prints nothing
```

Answer (score 4):

You could `echo $ENV_VAR1`, and use `communicate` to return the result from stdout:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen('source /path/to/file/env.sh; echo $ENV_VAR1', 
                        stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
env_var1, err = proc.communicate()
print(env_var1)
```

Another option might be to use [Miki Tebeka's `source` function](http://pythonwise.blogspot.fr/2010/04/sourcing-shell-script.html):

```
import subprocess
import os

def source(script, update=True):
    """
    source a file and return the environment as a dict.
    http://pythonwise.blogspot.fr/2010/04/sourcing-shell-script.html (Miki Tebeka)
    """
    proc = subprocess.Popen("source %s; env -0" % script, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                            shell=True)
    output, err = proc.communicate()
    env = dict((line.split("=", 1) for line in output.split('\x00') if line))
    if update:
        os.environ.update(env)
    return env

source('/path/to/env.sh')
print(os.environ['ENV_VAR1'])
```

If `/path/to/file/env.sh` contains

```
ENV_VAR1=FOO
export ENV_VAR1
```

the script above prints

```
FOO
```

Above, [I made a small change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20669683/190597) to
the function so that `env` uses a null byte (`\x00`) to separate output
lines. This makes it possible to parse name/value pairs that span multiple
lines.

Comment: good solution for bash, but not working is the sourcefile is `tcsh` file, `proc.communicate()` returns empty tuple

Comment: Using dot, as in `. /path/to/env.sh`, to source a file is a bash-ism. I think both bash and tcsh can use `source /path/to/env.sh` however. I've changed the code (in the `source` function) above to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a Python issue.  Environment variables are only visible to the process in which they are set and any child processes.  In these examples you are trying to set environment variables in a child and access them from the parent, which simply doesn't work.

If you want to communicate these values back to the parent you will need to arrange for some sort of explicit communication (e.g, having the child write the values to stdout and read them from the parent).

Comment: OP doesn't say it is an issue. Looks like he/she needs a way to save context between subsequent shell calls