# Python 2.7 keep env variables from a subprocess

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, variables, subprocess

I'm calling a bash script which is exporting a few variables, i found a way to get those variables and it's working, once i'm trying to add to args to my bash script it's failing.
Here is part of my python script:

```
bash_script = "./testBash.sh"
script_execution = Popen(["bash", "-c", "trap 'env' exit; source \"$1\"  > /dev/null 2>&1",

                                  "_", bash_script], shell=False, stdout=PIPE)
err_code = script_execution.wait()
variables = script_execution.communicate()[0]
```

This is my sample Bash script:

```
export var1="test1"

export var2=$var1/test2

echo "this is firsr var: var1=$var1"
echo "this is the second var: var2=$var2"
```

Once i'm changing the `bash_script = "./testBash.sh"` to `bash_script = "./testBash.sh test test"`
I'm not getting back the exported variables from the bash script into the `variables` variable in the Python script.
The provided above is a sample, and of course my real scripts are much more bigger.

Comment: I don't think you can get the environment back automatically in a reasonably portable way. What you could do if it suits you is to could use a system where your script calls a callback script that records the environment and transfers it to the original script (or just having your shell script just dumping the environment to a file that you could read, or even via `stdout`).

Comment: What do you get in the `variables`?

Comment: A list of all the environment variables including those that I've exported in the bash script

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: related: [Calling the “source” command from subprocess.Popen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22086176/4279)

Answer (score 1):

If you change `bash_script = "./testBash.sh"` to `bash_script = "./testBash.sh test test"` then the name of the bash_script changes to `"./testBash.sh test test"`. The `'test test'` is not interpreted as separate arguments.

Instead, add the extra arguments to the list being passed to `Popen`:

```
bash_script = "./testBash.sh"
script_execution = Popen(
["bash", "-c", "trap 'env' exit; source \"$1\"  > /dev/null 2>&1",
 "_", bash_script, 'test', 'test'], shell=False, stdout=PIPE)
```

Then `err_code` will be 0 (indicating success), instead of 1. It's not clear from your posted code however what you want to happen. The extra `test` arguments are ignored.

The extra argument are received by the bash script, however. If instead you put

```
export var1="$2"
```

in `testBash.sh`, then the `variables` (in the Python script) would contain

```
var1=test
```

---

You might also find it more convenient to use

```
import subprocess
import os

def source(script, update=True):
    """
    http://pythonwise.blogspot.fr/2010/04/sourcing-shell-script.html (Miki Tebeka)
    http://stackoverflow.com/a/20669683/190597 (unutbu)
    """
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
        ". %s; env -0" % script, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    output = proc.communicate()[0]
    env = dict((line.split("=", 1) for line in output.split('\x00') if line))
    if update:
        os.environ.update(env)
    return env

bash_script = "./testBash.sh"
variables = source(bash_script)
print(variables)
```

which yields the environment variables

```
{ 'var1': 'test1', 'var2': 'test1/test2', ... }
```

in a dict.