# How come Python subprocess can run a command which is not in path?

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I want to use Python's `subprocess.check_output` to check if the command `python` is in `PATH` and its version. The funny thing is that `check_output` is able to run the command `python` even if it's not in `PATH`:

```
C:\Users\Aivar\Desktop>set PATH=blahblah

C:\Users\Aivar\Desktop>python --version
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Aivar\Desktop>c:\python35\python -c ^
More? "import subprocess; ^
More? print(subprocess.check_output(['python', '--version']))"
b'Python 3.5.1\r\n'

C:\Users\Aivar\Desktop>c:\python35\python -c ^
More? "import os; print(os.environ['PATH'])"
blahblah
```

Can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: Can it be that the location of parent executable (`c:\python35\python` in my case) affects the search of commands? Can someone confirm this?

Comment: Try and check what `subprocess.check_output(['echo', '%CD%'])` returns to see your working directory.

Comment: @JoeZocker, your snippet shows that working directory is the same where I executed Python and what is shown in the shell prompt

Comment: Check out [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5659249/3714940) answer. Add `shell = True` to your `check_output()` call and you should get the expected outcome (I get `'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command...`)

Comment: [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425) always checks the application directory first, followed by the working directory, `%SystemRoot%\System32`, `%SystemRoot%`, and then the `PATH` directories.

Comment: In Vista+ you can force `CreateProcess` and cmd.exe to skip searching the working directory (but not the application directory) by defining the environment variable [`NoDefaultCurrentDirectoryInExePath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684269).

Comment: If you define an [`App Paths` key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872121#appPaths) for Python, then you can run `start python` from the command prompt, or to have cmd use the current console window and wait, for example, `start /b /w  python -c  "import sys; print(sys.executable)"`. In your case you can add this key from the command prompt using `reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\python.exe" /ve /d "\"C:\Python35\python.exe\""`.