# Execute a shell command with Python

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, pelican

I'm trying to execute a shell command using Python's subprocess. This is how I do it:

```
pelican = 'pelican content -s /home/pelican/publishconf.pyt -D --ignore-cache'
subprocess.call(pelican, shell=True)
```

But the response is `command not found`. It doesn't have a problem when I write in my command line.

My question is how can I execute a shell command using python  that behaves **just** like I would type it in?

Comment: try to `os.popen('your command')`

Comment: Or try: `subprocess.call(pelican.split(" "), shell=True)`

Comment: What does the split do in this case?
With os.popen I get /bin/sh: 1: pelican: not found

Comment: Sounds like there's a path issue, since the `pelican` command can't be found.  Also, `.split()` causes a list to be returned with the parts of the command (`pelican.split(" ")` => `["pelican", "content", "-s", "/home/pelican/publishconf.pyt", "-D", "--ignore-cache"]`.  It's generally a better approach since argument quoting can be done correctly (though I wouldn't necessarily use spilt to do this, try [shlex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html))--as suggested in the [Frequently Used Arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) docs.

Comment: Since the path appears to be a problem, it might be helpful to make sure that the path contains the pelican executable `subprocess.call("env", shell=True)`.

Comment: I did `which pelican` and got the abs path of pelican.
Then the problem is all the imported modules give me errors, I wonder if its possible to just make it work like I would do it using the shell.

Comment: `str.split` is not guaranteed to correctly parse a command line; consider `'pelican content -s "/home/pelican/my config.pyt" -D --ignore-cache'`. You should define a explicit *list* `["pelican", "content", "-s", "/home/pelican/my config.pyt", "-D", "--ignore-cache"]` and pass that as the first argument to `call` (with `shell=False`, the default, instead).

Comment: The issue is with your `PATH`, not with your code (though passing the command as a list with `shell=False` is [generally recommended](/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)) so you need to show us your `PATH`, the location of `pelican`, and the errors you get when you invoke it with the correct path (if it's a Python module, using `import pelican` would probably be a way better design).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5658622/1135424