# How to tell Flask path to a application binary

Tags: python

I want to be able to send commands to my air purifier via Flask, so I can use its functions with my home automation in webcore.

Here is the python snippet

```
from flask import Flask
import subprocess
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/status')

def my_command():
        cmd = 'airctrl --ipaddr 192.168.99.55 --protocol coap --mode S'
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        out,err = p.communicate()
        return out

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    app.run(host="192.168.99.45", port=5000, debug=True)
```

What will always return

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'airctrl --ipaddr 192.168.99.55 --protocol coap --mode S': 'airctrl --ipaddr 192.168.99.55 --protocol coap --mode S'
```

How can I tell flask, wehre to find "airctrl"?

I have tried

```
 cmd = '/usr/local/bin/airctrl', 'airctrl --ipaddr 192.168.99.55 --protocol coap --mode S'
```

which will return nothing but also do nothing.

Reallay appreciate your help, as you can see I am a total beginner and have googled for solutions for hours now.

Thank you,

Thomas

Comment: why don't you try a full path to the executable?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment above one solution is to specify the absolute path. Adapted to your example it would be this:

```py
cmd = '/usr/local/bin/airctrl --ipaddr 192.168.99.55 --protocol coap --mode S'
```

Also read [the Python documentation regarding Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) and e.g. [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658622/python-subprocess-popen-environment-path), which presents an alternative solution using `shell=True`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `shell=True` did the trick for me. It seems I didn't even know what exactly to look up. So thanks for pointing me at the right answer. Here is how the endpoints look now.

```
@app.route('/sleep')

def sleepmode():
        cmd = ["airctrl --ipaddr 192.168.99.55 --protocol coap --mode S"]
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        out,err = p.communicate()
        return out
```

Adding just the full path, I ran into a authentication error