# How to correctly input windows path to python subprocess argument

Tags: python, windows, path

I would like to open a windows application by using python `subprocess`, I can open the application in shell by command: `start "C:\Windows\notepad.exe"`, however when I try to use `subprocess` it gives `FileNotFoundError`, I tired:

```
subprocess.run(['start', '"C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe"'])
subprocess.run(['start', "C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe"])
subprocess.run(['start', "C:\Windows\notepad.exe"])
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just `subprocess.run(['C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe'])`? Are there special requirements to use `start`?

Comment: The duplicate is less than stellar, this is a common FAQ but I suddenly can't find a better one for this particular problem. Anyway, as explained in a separate comment, you need `shell=True` because `start` is a feature of the legacy CMD shell on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just check another related thread ([python subprocess Popen environment PATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658622/python-subprocess-popen-environment-path)).

EDIT:Subprocess with default options uses Shell=False, you need the Shell because you invoke a shell program.
From [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)   :

> On Windows with shell=True, the COMSPEC environment variable specifies
> the default shell. The only time you need to specify shell=True on
> Windows is when the command you wish to execute is built into the
> shell (e.g. dir or copy). You do not need shell=True to run a batch
> file or console-based executable.

I tested without `start` and adding `Shell=True` and both seem to work.

**1st option:**

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['C:/Windows/notepad.exe'])
```

**2nd option:**

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['start', 'C:/Windows/notepad.exe'], shell=True)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: The solution works but the explanation is wrong. You need `shell=True` because `start` is a command of the CMD shell on Windows, and so without it, Windows can't find a command named `start`.

Comment: @tripleee, According to your suggestion I have modified the paragraph, It was somewhat inaccurate.