# Subprocess Environment Variables and Python - pdflatex and git

Tags: python, linux, shell, subprocess, pdflatex

I am trying to use pdflatex to compile some `.tex` documents that I am automatically producing by using Python. When trying to use `pdflatex` by itself it does nothing, as remarked by other users, even by using `call` or other variations therein. So the solution I have found is to use the full path to the `pdflatex` executable. Assume that the path to `pdflatex` is

```
/usr/local/pdflatex_path/pdflatex
```

No problem, I can call `pdflatex` from `subprocess` without any problem:

```py
subprocess.run(
   ["/usr/local/pdflatex_path/pdflatex", file], cwd=directory, shell=False
)
```

This compiles without any problem. This is supposed to be machine independent since I have other Linux machines in which I wish to use the same script. So I figured, I could retrieve the path to `pdflatex` using the which command:

```py
 results = subprocess.run(
    ["which", "pdflatex"], shell=False, capture_output=True
)
 path = results.stdout.decode("utf-8")
```

and then use the resultant `path` to call it from the machine. However, this is not working either! The `which` command to retrieve the path works on other commands like `git`, but not on `pdflatex`, whereas the terminal does. I suspect that it's because `git` is located in `/usr/bin/...` but pdflatex is in `/usr/local/...`. How do I make `subprocess` include `/usr/local` and subfolders? Even setting `shell=False` doesn't work. I could include the path manually to the `.bashrc` file, but it would defeat the purpose (for the most part).

## Example

```py
result0 = subprocess.run(
    ["which", "git"], shell=False, capture_output=True
)
result1 = subprocess.run(
    ["which", "pdflatex"], shell=False, capture_output=True
)
 
print("git path: ", result0.stdout.decode("utf-8"))
print("pdflatex path: ", result1.stdout.decode("utf-8"))
```

results in:

```
   git path: /usr/bin/git
   pdflatex path:
```

whereas in the terminal:

```
which git
which pdflatex
```

results in:

```
/usr/bin/git
/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex
```

### Questions

Are there any workarounds to this? Or, what is going on?

### Update (2023/11/11):

Apparently it's a PyCharm problem, when running from the shell it works perfectly. It might be that PyCharm has its own standard PATH variables and additional paths need to be added manually.

Next time just check that this might be the issue.

Comment: Are you sure that your pdflatex executable is in your path? If you open a terminal and type `which pdflatex`, is it returning the full path or an `/usr/bin/which: no pdflatex in ...`

Comment: It's returning the path alright, as stated in the example: `/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex`

Comment: There is which implemented in python, do not call subprocess. Use text=true. `How do I make subprocess include /usr/local and subfolders?` which abd any other commands searches PATH variable. You can add path to PATH

Comment: I didn't know about that module...? Will try it out... thanks.

Comment: Here a link to a `which` python function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html?#shutil.which.

Comment: @ndclt, also tried with the `shutil` package and get the same result.

Comment: @Andrumen1 I think this answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5659249.

Comment: @Andrumen1 you could also print your path value in Python with `os.environ["PATH"]` to be sure that the path is the same than the one in the terminal.

Comment: Thanks, will try it. I do need some time though before getting back to you.

Comment: @ndclt, really weird, but it's happening as you have said. Will consider it for next time, but kind of annoying, TBH. Please set it as answer so it can be discussed or I can accept your answer: Thanks!

Comment: How are you _starting_ the Python interpreter? If it's started from a shell, it'll interpret that shell's PATH. If you're starting it from a GUI or a systemd service, that's _not a shell_ and can have a different initial PATH; programs get environment variables from the program that started them, so you have to look at who the parents are.

Comment: ...so if you configured that environment variable in your `.bashrc`, f/e, then you _shouldn't expect_ it to be present in the first place for things that weren't started from bash.

Comment: How to configure environment variables for programs started from a GUI is configuration _for that GUI_, and you haven't told us which one you use (GNOME? KDE? XFCE? ...).

Comment: ...over at SuperUser, https://superuser.com/questions/19044/how-do-i-set-an-environmental-variable-for-a-gnome-session recommends editing `~/.gnomerc` for GNOME, or creating files in `~/.kde/env` with `key=var` pairings for KDE, or `~/.config/environment.d` as a more modern equivalent for operating systems where user sessions are managed by systemd.