# Python: Exporting environment variables in subprocess.Popen(..)

Tags: python, python-2.7, environment-variables

I am having an issue with setting an environment variable on a call to `subprocess.Popen`. The environment variable does not seem to be getting set. Any suggestions on how to properly set environmental variables for a Python commandline call?

My goal is to run a script that uses an environmental variable determined from my Python code:

```
d = dict(os.environ)
d["TEST_VARIABLE"] = str(1234)
subprocess.Popen('/usr/bin/mybinary', env=d).wait()
```

but the script reacts as if the variable has never been set

Here is my attempt to test, using Python's interactive interpreter:

```
d = dict(os.environ)
d["TEST_VARIABLE"] = str(1234)
subprocess.Popen(['/bin/echo', '$TEST_VARIABLE'], env=d).wait()
```

and the output is:

```
"$TEST_VARIABLE"
0
```

I thought `env=d` should set the environment for the subprocess, but it apparently does not. Any suggestions on how to correct this issue?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The substitution of environment variables *on the command line* is done by the shell, not by /bin/echo. So you need to run the command in a shell to get the substitution:

```
In [22]: subprocess.Popen('/bin/echo $TEST_VARIABLE', shell=True, env=d).wait()
1234
Out[22]: 0
```

That doesn't mean the environment variable is not set when `shell=False`, however. Even without `shell=True`, the executable does see the enviroment variables set by the `env` parameter. For example, `date` is affected by the `TZ` environment variable:

```
In [23]: subprocess.Popen(["date"], env={'TZ': 'America/New_York'}).wait()
Wed Oct 29 22:05:52 EDT 2014
Out[23]: 0

In [24]: subprocess.Popen(["date"], env={'TZ': 'Asia/Taipei'}).wait()
Thu Oct 30 10:06:05 CST 2014
Out[24]: 0
```

Answer (score 23):

For Python 3.5 and newer, you can use [unpacking generalizations](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-448), eg:

```
env = {
    **os.environ,
    "TEST_VARIABLE": str(1234),
}
subprocess.Popen('/usr/bin/mybinary', env=env).wait()
```

Answer (score 7):

You should use `os.environ.copy()` to make it work. It creates a copy of the entire environment dictionary which you can then modify before passing it on to the subprocess, without modifying the current process environment.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231227/python-subprocess-popen-with-a-modified-environment).

Comment: The problem is not the environment but the substitution, as explained by the accepted answer.

Comment: True, but the title of post states "Exporting," so this is useful.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do it and set them up forever into a user account you can use setx but if you want as global you can use setx /M but for that you might need elevation, (i am using windows as example, (for linux you can use export i think)

## in windows

```
import subprocess
exp = 'setx hi2 "youAsWell"'
subprocess.Popen(exp, shell=True).wait()
```

after running that you can go to the environments and see how they been added into my user environments

[image]