# Error Python tabula with two versions of Java installed

Tags: java, python, subprocess, environment-variables, tabula

I have 2 versions of Java installed, one for tabula-py, and the other for Teradata (work-related). I’ve only been able to get Java 1.8 to work with tabula-py, and 1.7 is what works with our version of Teradata in my company.

I’ve removed any environment variable reference to java, with the exception of version 1.8, which I did by creating its own variable and adding it to the 'PATH' (%JAVA_HOME%\bin).
However, it doesn’t matter what I do, it always returns an error that the java filepath doesn’t exist. When I uninstall 1.7 it works every time, but whenever I have it installed it breaks.
When I check for the java version on the command line it returns: 
'''*Java version “1.7.0_80”*'''
I’ve looked through the code, and in util.py I saw that it referenced 'subprocess.check_output' using the code below:

'''
res = subprocess.check_output(["java", "-version"], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
'''

After researching a bit, I read that it has something to do with shell vs echo/bin. I can’t make any sense of it. ([Python: Exporting environment variables in subprocess.Popen(..)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643719/python-exporting-environment-variables-in-subprocess-popen))

Could someone please help me know what I’m doing wrong?

Comment: [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one version of java at a time, which path is set in environment variable in priority, but alternatively you can set temporary path from command prompt and you can select whatever version you want to use.

**In command prompt just use this command**

```
set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin
```

**Note**: You have to set path every time when you open command prompt as this is a temporary path.

Comment: Thank you! 
Is there any way I can do that within a python module? I would hate to have to adjust it every time I want to use that library.

Comment: Yes, For that you have to set path in environment variable. And only one java version can be run at a time when you set path in environment variable.