# set environ using subprocess module using python

Tags: python, subprocess

I am set the environ using os module

```
import os
os.putenv('test','/usr/lib/jvm')
os.system('bash')
```

How to set using subprocess

`import subprocess`

NB: Please don't write a shell script and call using subprocess

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Exporting environment variables in subprocess.Popen(..)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643719/python-exporting-environment-variables-in-subprocess-popen)

Comment: @RandomDavis can you help in writing using subprocess

Comment: @RandomDavis tried with `import subprocess` subprocess.Popen('/usr/lib/jvm $test', shell=True, env=d).wait()

Comment: @Maws, if you [edit] the question to show a specific attempt that reflects _trying_ to use the linked duplicate's answer and not getting the expected results, that might then be a new, distinct, non-duplicative question. That said, please make sure that test is actually something _people other than you_ can be expected to successfully run without making assumptions about other things you did -- that's not the case for the code fragment in your comment above.

Comment: (to explain that "not the case" assertion: (1) on most systems, `/usr/lib/jvm` is a directory, not an executable, so it isn't expected to be something that can be executed ever; (2) you aren't showing `test` being inserted into `d`; (3) you aren't showing actual and expected output that would _reflect_ whether `test` is being successfully substituted by the shell -- though I'd expect running `/usr/lib/jvm` to _always_ fail, whether that substitution happens or not).