# How to load jar file and support files placed at different location

Tags: python, jar

I am creating a python program that runs a jar file. The jar file and some support files are placed in a different location than the python program's directory. I tried adding jar file path to `sys.path` but it's unable to access the file from there, however the path is added to `sys.path` correctly. How can I get this working?

jar file location: `E:\data`

python file location: `C:\Users\user\Desktop`

I am using `subprocess` to call the jar file, the code looks like:

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess as sp

class abc():
    def __init__(self):
        sys.path.append(r'E:\data')

    def run(self):
        print sys.path
        env = dict(os.environ)
        env['JAVA_OPTS'] = '-Xms256m -Xmx256m -Xss1024k'
        sp.call(['java', '-jar', 'file.jar'], env=env)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    o = abc()
    o.run()
```

After running above code, I get an error saying:

`Error: Unable to access jarfile file.jar`

Comment: I know it's not a good way to include absolute path but what happens when you reference absolute path in place of 'file.jar'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python subprocess/Popen with a modified environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231227/python-subprocess-popen-with-a-modified-environment)

Comment: @mario23 I can use absolute path in place of 'file.jar' but there are some support files as well which are required in order to execute file.jar That's why I need to add the path to some env variable.

Answer (score 4):

What if you just change your working directory:

```
import os
cwd = os.getcwd() #current directory
os.chdir('path/to/jar')
... # run file
...
os.chdir(cwd)
```

Comment: That works fine! But I don't want to use it that way because there might be a case when it has to share some data from/at both locations. I wanted to add jar file path to python path as a permanent path, so that I would be able to access any of those paths.

Answer (score 2):

`sys.path` and `PYTHONPATH` are used when importing python modules

When executing commands, the operating system lookup the command in its system path (`%PATH%` on Windows).

There is no lookup path for data / filenames passed as argument.

When using sp.call() the system path lookup uses whatever directory the script has been launched from. So you need to either change dir to `E:\DATA` or use the absolute path:

```
sp.call(['java', '-jar', 'E:\DATA\file.jar'], env=env)
```

There are plenty of env variable on Windows:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Default_values

Comment: I can use absolute path in place of 'file.jar' but there are some support files as well which are required in order to execute file.jar That's why I need to add the path to some env variable. Providing complete path to just jar doesn't work.

Comment: Then that E:\DATA\ can be a class attribute which you reuse everywhere.  Or you could `os.chdir('E:\DATA\')` as suggested by Dashing Adam Hughes, thus file operations will be relative to E:\DATA\.

Comment: yeah, had to use os.chdir()