# Compiling C++ code with g++ from Python script on Windows

Tags: python, c++, g++, popen

I'm trying to write a Python script that calls g++.exe via subprocess.Popen() and uses it to compile a .cpp file into an .exe. The problem is that no matter how I try to pass the path to the source file, I get the following error:

> g++.exe: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory

My directory structure is as follows:

```
D:/Test/test.py
D:/Test/external/mingw64/g++.exe
D:/Test/c/client/client.cpp
```

And my code is:

```
import os, subprocess

class builder():
    def __init__(self):
        self.gccPath = os.path.abspath("external/mingw64/g++.exe")
        self.sourceDir = os.path.abspath("c/client")
        self.fileName = "client.cpp"
        self.sourceFile = os.path.join(self.sourceDir, self.fileName)

    def run(self):
        command = [self.gccPath, self.sourceFile , "-o", "client.exe"]
        print command
        process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        n=1
        while True:
            nextLine = process.stdout.readline()
            if nextLine == '' and process.poll() != None:
                break
            if nextLine != "" and nextLine != None:
                print n, nextLine
            n=n+1

builder = builder()
builder.run()
```

Just some of the ways I've tried to pass the path:

```
Command: ["D:\\Test\\external\\mingw64\\g++.exe", "c/client/client.cpp", "-o", "client.exe"]
Command: ["D:\\Test\\external\\mingw64\\g++.exe", "c\\client\\client.cpp", "-o", "client.exe"]
Command: ["D:\\Test\\external\\mingw64\\g++.exe", "D:\\Test\\c\\client\\client.cpp", "-o", "client.exe"]
```

I also tried passing cwd to Popen:

```
command = [self.gccPath, "client.cpp", "-o", "client.exe"]
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, cwd=self.sourceDir, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Always the same error. I've used Popen plenty of times before and it's usually a trivial matter, so I'm pretty stumped right now as to what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @PM2Ring - But I'm not joining two absolute paths with that line, I'm joining an absolute path with a string.

I'm not too worried about path looks, they're only being printed out for debug purposes. If and when I get this working all prints will be removed anyways.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to make a build-system. Why not just use an existing one like SCons (http://scons.org/) or CMake (https://cmake.org/) ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not the `client.cpp` file that is not found, but the `g++.exe`. You can know that because it is `CreateProcess` that generates the error. If it was the cpp file, `CreateProcess` would succeed, and only then would the compiler return with an error.

```
os.path.abspath("external/mingw64/g++.exe")
```

This builds an absolute path from the relative path you give. Relative means relative to current directory, not to the directory of the python file.

If your g++ is in a fixed tree, a better way should be to construct the path from the script name, like this:

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "external/mingw64/g++.exe")
```

Holds true for other places where you use `abspath` for something not relative to current working directory.

Comment: Trying that, I just get "The system cannot find the path specified". I'm assuming this time it's an actual compiler error and the client.cpp is the issue?

Comment: Could be. Is an exception raised, and if so, what is it?

Comment: Also, if you still have `cwd=self.sourceDir`, check that it's a valid path as well (constructing it using `__file__` the same way you just changed `gccPath`).

Comment: No exceptions, the only output is `1 The system cannot find the path specified`. When I try to construct self.sourceDir that way, there's an exception from subprocess (_execute_child); WindowsError: [Error 267] The directory name is invalid.

Comment: If  no exceptions, then `Popen` succeeds, and the error you see is from `g++.exe`. So you successfuly fixed the path to g++. Next step, fix the path to `client.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my own problem and get a working .exe with the following code:

```
import os, subprocess, json, glob

class client():
    def __init__(self):
        self.gccDir = os.path.abspath("external/mingw64")
        self.sourceDir = "c/client"
        self.fileName = "client.cpp"
        self.sourceFile = os.path.join(self.sourceDir, self.fileName)
        self.destFile = self.sourceFile.replace(".cpp", ".exe")

    def run(self):
        srcFiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(self.sourceDir+"/*.cpp"))
        srcFiles.remove(self.sourceFile)
        myEnv = os.environ.copy()
        myEnv["PATH"] = myEnv["PATH"]+";"+self.gccDir
        command = ["g++.exe", self.sourceFile, " ".join([x for x in srcFiles]), "-std=c++11", "-Os", "-o", self.destFile]
        process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, env=myEnv, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        n=1
        while True:
            nextLine = process.stdout.readline()
            if nextLine == '' and process.poll() != None:
                break
            if nextLine != "" and nextLine != None:
                print n, nextLine
            n=n+1
```

The command ends up being:

```
['g++.exe', 'c/client\\client.cpp', 'c/client\\utils.cpp', '-std=c++11', '-Os', '-o', 'c/\\client.exe']
```

Paths look ugly but work. The manual removing of sourceFile from srcFiles is a bit clumsy, but it seems necessary that the main file is the first to be referenced in the command.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231227/python-subprocess-popen-with-a-modified-environment) was very useful and allowed me to temporarily set the PATH environment variable to whatever directory I had g++.exe in. Thanks to everyone for trying to help.