# How to call LC_ALL=C sort from python subprocess

Tags: python, sorting, subprocess

How to call `LC_ALL=C sort -k1 file -o file` with python `subprocess`?

When I try:
`subprocess.check_call(["LC_ALL=C sort -k1 {} -o {}".format(file,file)])`

Following error occurs:
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'LC_ALL=C sort -k1 file.txt -o file.txt'`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231227/python-subprocess-popen-with-a-modified-environment

Answer (score 4):

The syntax `var=value command` is shell syntax to set an environment variable and run a command. `subprocess` by default does not offer a shell (and though you can get one with `shell=True` you should generally try to avoid this if you can). The way to do this in Python is to pass in a dictionary of variables with `env`.

```
myenv = os.environ.copy()
myenv['LC_ALL'] = 'C'
subprocess.check_call(['sort', '-k1', file, '-o', file], env=myenv)
```

Python is perfectly capable of sorting a sequence of lines internally; avoiding the external process entirely is an even better solution.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out; edited now to copy os.environ

Comment: That's a cleaner approach than the one I used; might adopt it. :)

Answer (score 3):

#### Assignments are *shell syntax*.

When you don't set `shell=True`, there is no shell, so there's nothing available to parse and honor the assignment.

---

#### Just setting `shell=True` would cause security bugs.

If your filename contains `$(rm -rf ~)`, using `''.format()` to inject it is dangerous.

---

#### So generate an environment that has `LC_ALL` added to it, with a value of `C`:

```
sort_env = os.environ.copy()
sort_env['LC_ALL'] = 'C'

subprocess.check_call(['sort', '-k1', file, '-o', file], env=sort_env)
```

---

#### Or use `shell=True`, but pass arguments out-of-band:

When a list is passed to `shell=True`, the first element is treated as the script to interpret; the second as `$0` in the context of that script; the third as `$1`, etc. Thus:

```
subprocess.check_call(['LC_ALL=C sort -k1 "$1" -o "$2"', '_', file, file])
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a dict of the environmental variables as the `env` kwarg to [the subprocess invocation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

```
    Python 2.7.14 (default, Mar 22 2018, 14:43:05)

    In [1]: import subprocess

    In [2]: subprocess.check_call(["env"], env={'LC_ALL': 'C'})
    LC_ALL=C
```