# How to pass the proxy settings/credentials to command prompt using python so that the later commands in the same python code get access to internet?

Tags: python, proxy, operating-system, subprocess, command-prompt

Some of the commands in my python code uses the internet to download the required files. Unfortunately I am using a proxy internet connection.

I am aware that these commands are used for getting internet in cmd.exe( I tried manually by typing the below mentioned commands in cmd prompt and later accessing net in the same)

```
set http_proxy=http://username:password@your_proxy:your_port 
set https_proxy=https://username:password@your_proxy:your_port
```

But, I am unable to pass these commands from python code itself so that I need not type them manually every time I run a code. Some of the links would be using http and others use https. how should i address this in the code?

I tried this but it did not worked :

```
import os
proxy = "set https_proxy=https://username:password@your_proxy:your_port"
os.system(proxy)
import numpy
...........my code........
```

where I was wrong and what is the correct procedure to achieve my requirement ? And can I use subprocess in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass system ENV :

```
os.environ["http_proxy"] = "http://username:password@your_proxy:your_port"
```

Comment: can I replace os with subprocess ?

Comment: @SaiKiran probably yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231227/python-subprocess-popen-with-a-modified-environment

Comment: I was getting error `connection time out : connect` while trying to download from http . when I used the above mentioned command

Comment: and there is no need of `set` before `http://username:password@your_proxy:your_port` as we are supposed to use or what ?

Comment: @xmojmr can you explain me briefly . I couldn't understand how to incorporate sub process in my case from what they have did.

Comment: @SaiKiran what I understood from the linked question is that you should create copy of the current environment `os.environ.copy()`, modify the copy (dictionary) by setting the `"http_proxy"` and `"https_proxy"` keys and then use the copy to open subprocess with `subprocess.Popen(my_command, env=my_env)` call

Comment: `os.environ[" http_proxy"] = "http://username:password@your_proxy:your_port"` It is not working for me.

Comment: do you test this whith the white space between `"` and `http_proxy` ?

Comment: I mean you need to try this wihtout the sapce that was a typo, I edited my answer also

Comment: I tried after removing the white space too. But it din't worked

Comment: could you please write down the code , how you call the proxy when connecting to the internet.