# How to close subprocess in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a python code where i am using subprocess to get output of command "which opatch" in a function which gets output as unix path to getOpatch. Once that is done, how do I close the subprocess opened using Popen. Below is the code i use for calling subprocess. Thanks in advance.

```
import os
import subprocess

os.environ["ORACLE_HOME"] = X
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + os.pathsep.join([X + "/OPatch"])
getOpatch = subprocess.Popen("which opatch", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
op_path = getOpatch.read()
```

Comment: Issue is when i run different function2 which has diff inputs ($PATH), subprocess variable2 is returning same value as in function1

Comment: Please clarify your question. The subprocess automatically closes when done, there is no need to do so manually. Is your problem that your changes to ``os.environ`` persist?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python subprocess/Popen with a modified environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231227/python-subprocess-popen-with-a-modified-environment)

Comment: os.environ value changes when passing new value everytime but subprocess.Popen when fetching output of "which opatch" not changing to the latest.

Comment: You are *appending* to ``PATH`` every time the function is called, and never remove the added sub-path. Check the linked question on how to use an environment only for a single ``subprocess``.

Comment: Thanks MisterMiyagi...i get your point. Will check the suggestion and get back to you.

Comment: I am unable to get it from the link you provided. Can you able to give me example how to remove the path variable that is added using os.environ.

Comment: You should use a context manager for this: from docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html : "Popen objects are supported as context managers via the with statement: on exit, standard file descriptors are closed, and the process is waited for. `with Popen(["ifconfig"], stdout=PIPE) as proc: log.write(proc.stdout.read())`"

Answer (score 2):

`subprocess.terminate()` 
should kill it

Comment: i am getting below error when using terminate.   File "/z01/EBS_PATCH_TOOL/modules_seq.py", line 106, in OHome_1012
    subprocess.terminate()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'terminate'

Comment: This is because it should be `getOpatch.terminate()`. It is the `Popen` instance that has the `terminate` method, not `subprocess` directly.

Comment: In any case, the command that is launched in this example (essentially `sh -c 'which opatch'`) will exit immediately after printing a line of output, so there is no good reason to try to terminate it.