# Way to export path that get resolved and picked by the subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I been trying to run the ksh script from python using subprocess and need some help as environment variable are not being resolved which are being used inside the script. Any advice on proper way to export the path for subprocess to pick.

Tried to echo the path but it return same value with being resolved

```
import os
import subprocess as sp

os.environ['b_dir'] = /path/script/
os.environ['data_dir'] = /path/data/

r0 = sp.run(['echo','$b_dir'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
print(r0.stdout.decode())
r = sp.run(['ksh','$b_dir/dev/scriptname.ksh'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
print(r.stdout.decode())
```

output of r0 was
$b_dir

expecting:
/path/script/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python subprocess/Popen with a modified environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231227/python-subprocess-popen-with-a-modified-environment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a string to the command 'echo', something like
`echo '$b_dir'` in bash.

You could do it as follows:

```
r0 = sp.run(["echo", f"{os.environ.get('$b_dir')}"], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.STDOUT)
```

This `os.environ.get('$b_dir')` command will read the environment variable and pass its value as an argument in the *run* method.

Or you can pass the path directly by calling the *run* method.

```
r0 = sp.run(["echo", "/my/path/myfile"], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.STDOUT)
```