# Execute two commands with subprocess.Popen Python

Tags: python, batch-processing, popen, filenotfoundexception

I want to execute a batch file by calling it from a python script. The thing is that this batch needs **JAVA_HOME** to be set. I don't want to set this variable in the system env Variable, i want to do it from python. Is there anyway to execute two batch commands via Like this

```
p = Popen("""set JAVA_HOME=D:\GIT\G_ATC_FCT_SW_HSM_Daimler\Tools\jdk-8.0.242.08-hotspot;D:\\GIT\\G_ATC_FCT_SW_HSM_Daimler\\Tools\\plugins\\com.nxp.id.jcop.eclipse_6.0.0.8\\cmds\\converter.bat Java_Card_Converter-3.0.5""")
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

But i got this error `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The specified file could not be found`.
Is it possible to do it from popen ?

Comment: Your backslashes are not escaped (which is likely the source of the `FileNotFoundError`)

Comment: Also, if all else fails, you can make a batch file with the two commands and run that one via Popen

Comment: @GPhilo Thanks for your feed back i tested with double Backslashes but it's not fixing the problem i think that Popen can be used only for executing Batch or shell script. Also i don't want to create a batch script to do the two commands since i can do it from python.

Comment: Then since you don't actually need to run two commands, but only run the script with a modified environment, use the solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4453495/3214872

Comment: Thx @GPhilo the link that you gave me helped a lot, gonna validate the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response provided by @GPhilo helped me. Here is solution to my problem:

> Then since you don't actually need to run two commands, but only run the script with a modified environment, use the solution from here: [Python subprocess/Popen with a modified environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231227/python-subprocess-popen-with-a-modified-environment/4453495#4453495) – GPhilo