# FileNotFoundError: [Errno2]: No Such file or directory:

Tags: python, scripting, centos, wazuh, hardening

I am trying to make a server hardening script for my work, part of it is to install wazuh-agent on the servers that will be connected to a SIEM manager.

The script has 2 parts, one where it adds the repo entry - that works fine.

The second part installs the wazuh agent (code below). When I run the commands on the shell, they work fine but with the script it gives me the following error.

```
import os 
import subprocess

wazuhrepofile = "/etc/yum.repos.d/wazuh.repo"
wazuh = "wazuh-agent"
wazuhmanager = 'WAZUHMANAGER="10.0.0.2"'

def install_wazuh(wazuh, wazuhmanager, wazuhrepofile):
    subprocess.run([wazuhmgr ,'yum', 'install', '-y', wazuh], check=True)
    print("Wazuh Agent Installed")
    subprocess.run(['systemctl', 'daemon-reload'], check=True)
    print("Daemon Reloaded")
    subprocess.run(['systemctl', 'enable', wazuh])
    print("Wazuh Agent Enabled")
    subprocess.run(['systemctl', 'start', wazuh], check=True)
    print("Wazuh-Agent Service Started!")
    subprocess.run(['sed', '-i', '"s/^enabled=1/enabled=0/"', wazuhrepofile])


install_wazuh(wazuh, wazuhmgr, wazuhrepofile)
```

and the following is the error
[run error]

[image: 1]

Comment: in your first subprocess call there is an extra wazuhmgr variable that seems useless. It should stard by directly by 'yum' ...

Comment: Looks like You're trying to run a command with an env variable `WAZUHMANAGER="10.0.0.2"`.  I think that `subprocess.run` expects a command as the first argument. Check this thread to find out how to run a command with a modified environment:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231227/python-subprocess-popen-with-a-modified-environment

Comment: thanks man I'll check that out. I figured out a easy fix for now, instead of running a shell command - used a file.replace(old,new) to correct the file.

Answer (score 0):

hj.
Thanks for choosing Wazuh.

As it was stated, **subprocess.run** accepts a series of parameters, but it seems that the first one needs to be an actual command instead of a variable assignment.

What you are doing is passing the Manager IP to have the Agent auto-enroll to the Manager. Another possible way, would be to install the Agent and then use the **agent-auth** located on the /var/ossec/bin/ folder. This commands also allows the Agent to pass an Agent Name to the Manager, so it will show with on the alerts and the UI, for easier identification.

the command is: */var/ossec/bin/agent-auth -m MANAGER-IP -A AGENT-NAME*

For more information on agent registration visit [here](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/registering/index.html#register-agents) and for info on agent-auth tool, [here](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/registering/password-authorization-registration.html#password-authorization-registration)

In case you have any further questions, don't hesitate to ask.
Cheers