# How do change the env in subprocess?

Tags: python, environment-variables, subprocess, virtualenv

I do not understand the value of the env attribute in the Popen subprocess. I want to change the virtual environment of the python code I am running.

#### example

Suppose a file named subprocess_test.py which is run through virtual environment `venv_main`:

```py
# subprocess_test.py

cmd = f"C:/home/._venv/Scripts/python example.py".split()
sp = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, cwd="/home", env = "___________")
try:
    sp.wait(timeout=16)
    run_output, run_error = sp.communicate()
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    sp.kill()
    run_output, run_error = sp.communicate()
```

#### example.py

```py
import os
print(os.environ)
```

It do not print the details of venv which Suprocess command takes .i.e, `C:/home/._venv/Scripts` instead It print the details of environment from which subprocess_test.py executes i.e., `venv_main`

Maybe env attribute can solve my problem But I do not understand how env attribute work and what is the appropriate value of env?

Answer (score 0):

The `env` argument should be a dictionary where the key is the env var name. In general you want to make a copy of `os.environ` then modify it (e.g., by changing the value of `PATH`) to suit your needs. This is a FAQ. See, for example, [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231227/python-subprocess-popen-with-a-modified-environment).

Comment: but it didn't solve my problem