# Subprocess: How to run a command whose first argument is not a file?

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess

I am running a gcc command via python's `subprocess.run` as follows

```
cmdCompile="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib gcc foo.c"

subprocess.run(cmdCompile.split(' '), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,check=True)
```

I got an error saying

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib'
```

Apparently, the first argument of subprocess should not start with a non-file. How can I work around it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python subprocess/Popen with a modified environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231227/python-subprocess-popen-with-a-modified-environment)

Comment: You are trying to run a shell command. You need to pass the string to `subprocess.run` (do not call `.split()`) and set `shell=True`: `subprocess.run(cmdCompile, shell=True, ...)`...or set the environment in Python *before* calling `subprocess.run`, and remove it from your command line.