# Python unable to import custom module despite having __init__.py

Tags: python

I have a folder with a `__init__.py`

File __init__.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
flags="test"
```

File main.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
import foldername

def main():
    print foldername.flags

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Now, when I run `./main.py` (from inside the folder), I get the error

```
ImportError: No module named foldername
```

Comment: Make sure, that the parent directory of `foldername` is in your python path (environment variable `PYTHONPATH`).

Comment: you can't use `flags` - It should be `foldername.flags`.

Comment: Make sure your foldername is *not* also `main`. And `main.py` should *not* be inside the same folder.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: `main.py` may be inside the same folder. Python 2.7 even supports it explicitly with `__main__.py` name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run from the *parent* folder for `foldername`:

```sh
    $ python -m foldername.main
```

If you rename `main.py` to `__main__.py` then you could run it as (since Python 2.7):

```sh
    $ python -m foldername
```

`python -m` adds implicitly current directory to your python path (`sys.path`).

```
Parent Folder/
└── foldername
    ├── __init__.py
    │   #    flags="test"
    └── __main__.py
        #    import foldername
        #   
        #    def main():
        #        print foldername.flags
        #   
        #    if __name__=="__main__":
        #        main()
```

If the parent directory for `foldername` is in your python path then you could run the above commands from *any* directory.

Comment: Running from the parent folder of main gives: /usr/bin/python2: No module named foldername

Comment: @jck: move one directory up i.e., use the parent folder of *folder* "foldername".

Comment: Sorry. running from the home directory(Parent folder of foldername) also gives the same error.

Comment: @jck: I've added the directory layout. It should be clear what the "Parent Folder" is.

Answer (score 5):

[PYTHONPATH](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) issue.  Make sure that "foldername" is available in your path.  If you are running it from inside "foldername" it might not be available.  Try running from the parent of "foldername".

Here is [a question about finding your PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489599/how-do-i-find-out-my-python-path-using-python).

Comment: It is not `PYTHONPATH` issue. It is python path issue (`sys.path`). My `PYTHONPATH` environment variable is always empty. `python` implicitly adds script's directory to `sys.path`. Sometimes It is called `sys.path[0]` initialization for scripts.

Comment: Wow, this solved my mystery problem! I did not realize the parent path must also be in the PYTHONPATH! So the same script sitting a level above what I want to import runs fine. But once I move it into some sub-directory, it won't import even with the right sys.path - until I add the parent dir to sys.path that is. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your layout is like this:

```
./folder/__init__.py
./main.py
```

and there is **not file named `folder.py`**!

Change to the *parent* folder, so that `ls folder/__init__.py` works.

Next try running `python -c "import folder"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import the a module in python3 simply go to the root folder

```
python3 -mModuleName
```

Make sure you do not remove the `-m` before the module name and then this you can import this module anywhere inside the project directory.