# Kivy code working fine from the CMD python shell but not from a file saved at Desktop or any location

Tags: python, kivy

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class simple(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text = "Hello World")

if __name__ == "main__":
    simple().run()
```

The above code works fine when written in the **python CMD shell**, but this code does not works when saved in a **file**.

On **CMD python shell**:

[image]

From **IDLE, Sublime Text and different text editors** (The file is saved on Desktop):

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Imports working with raw file, but not in IDLE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772847/imports-working-with-raw-file-but-not-in-idle)

Comment: but this doesn't work with any editor

Comment: are you tried: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10772923/2419628 ?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. But with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer to my own question. The issue was with the python path. Since I was creating the file on Desktop. It was not reading the python or specifically kivy's path correctly. Solution for this is to create or save the project in a directory inside the python's directory. It worked for me.