# Pip install pynrrd

Tags: python, import, sdk, installation, pip

So I apologize in advance if this is really simple but I cannot seem to get the pynrrd package to import into pycharm.

I tried using `pip`

[image]

And I tried the instructions at the [repo](https://github.com/mhe/pynrrd)

[image]

but pycharm just isn't detecting module `nrrd`:

[image]

I am trying to get a hang of the [mouse connectivity sdk](http://alleninstitute.github.io/AllenSDK/connectivity.html) and it does mention at the bottom that:

> Warning The pynrrd package available on PyPI contains known issues on
>   Windows. If you are a Windows user, please install the latest version
>   available here: https://github.com/mhe/pynrrd.

I am indeed on a Windows machine and hence am trying to install the latest version.

UPDATE: As suggested below, here is what I get for the [Python Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489599/how-do-i-find-out-my-python-path-using-python)

```
 import sys
 print sys.path
['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\JetBrains\\PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.3\\helpers\\pydev', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python27\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\Sphinx-1.3.1-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\cryptography-0.9.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-18.0.1-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions', 'C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\MyFirstAllenBrain']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you check your the path variable `%PYTHON_PATH%`

I'm not sure but try changing the project root from `*/play*`  to  `*/play/working_directory*`

Comment: Check the updates in my question. Also, how do I change my project root? Google doesn't seem to be coming up with the answer

Comment: Wow. The old restart everything fixed it. :/ Guess I'll give you the credit because a while after checking the path variables and figuring out that nothing is wrong I promptly gave up. Should have given up earlier, lol.

Comment: @dirkHaupt  great !! :)