# Allen Brain Institute - Mouse Connectivity API and Mouse Connectivity Cache examples

Tags: python, allen-sdk

I'm trying to follow the [Mouse Connectivity sdk](http://alleninstitute.github.io/AllenSDK/connectivity.html) and get their two examples working.

`pd` returns None or all projection signal density experiments. Why might this be?

```
from allensdk.api.queries.mouse_connectivity_api import MouseConnectivityApi

mca = MouseConnectivityApi()

# get metadata for all non-Cre experiments
experiments = mca.experiment_source_search(injection_structures='root', transgenic_lines=0)

# download the projection density volume for one of the experiments
#pd = mca.download_projection_density('example.nrrd', experiments[0]['id'], resolution=25)

for exp in range(len(experiments)):
    pd = mca.download_projection_density('example.nrrd', experiments[exp]['id'], resolution=25)
    print(type(pd))
```

Results:

```
C:\Anaconda\python.exe C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/MyFirstAllenBrain/Test.py
<type 'NoneType'>
<type 'NoneType'>
<type 'NoneType'>
<type 'NoneType'>
<type 'NoneType'>
<type 'NoneType'>
... etc
```

The thing though is, is that `experiments` does recieve a value so it appears to be the case that the MouseConnectivityApi and nrrd (which I installed as per the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32240133/pip-install-pynrrd)) are working appropriately.

See here:
[image]

Right, and now the second example

```
from allensdk.core.mouse_connectivity_cache import MouseConnectivityCache

# tell the cache class what resolution (in microns) of data you want to download
mcc = MouseConnectivityCache(resolution=25)

# use the ontology class to get the id of the isocortex structure
ontology = mcc.get_ontology()
isocortex = ontology['Isocortex']

# a list of dictionaries containing metadata for non-Cre experiments
experiments = mcc.get_experiments(injection_structure_ids=isocortex['id'])

# download the projection density volume for one of the experiments
pd = mcc.get_projection_density(experiments[0]['id'])
```

This is copied word for word from Allen and yet this is the error message I get:

```
C:\Anaconda\python.exe C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/MyFirstAllenBrain/Test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/MyFirstAllenBrain/Test.py", line 14, in <module>
    pd = mcc.get_projection_density(experiments[0]['id'])
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\allensdk\core\mouse_connectivity_cache.py", line 170, in get_projection_density
    return nrrd.read(file_name)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nrrd.py", line 384, in read
    data = read_data(header, filehandle, filename)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nrrd.py", line 235, in read_data
    mmap.MAP_PRIVATE, mmap.PROT_READ)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MAP_PRIVATE'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Why might this occur?

And again as before (no need for another picture I assume), the `experiments` variable does recieve what appears to be values for each experiment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a Windows-specific issue with the pynrrd/master github repository right now.  I know that one specific revision works:

https://github.com/mhe/pynrrd/commit/3c0f3d577b0b435fb4825c14820322a574311af0

To install this revision from a windows command prompt, you can:

```
> git clone https://github.com/mhe/pynrrd.git
> cd pynrrd
> git checkout 3c0f3d5
> cd ..
> pip install --upgrade pynrrd\
```

The backslash on the end is important.  It tells pip to install from a local path instead of checking PyPI.

Issue logged: https://github.com/mhe/pynrrd/issues/18

Comment: I see, thanx. I've been looking at dual booting the PC at our lab with Ubuntu and it shouldn't be an issue as I'm just getting started. Would you recommend that we (and I suppose other researchers too) do that? I ask because If the Allen Institute - going forward - is likely going a more Linux route I'm more than happy to follow.

Comment: We are definitely aiming to support Windows users.  The pynrrd developers are a bit more linux-oriented, but I'm working with them to resolve this issue.   Thanks for your patience.

Comment: So this did solve my second issue with the Mouse Connectivity Cache - i.e. It gave me the projection density volume but my first problem remains unresolved. I still get nothing but NoneTypes when I run my code. Is that normal?

an issue with download_projection_density perhaps?

Comment: Good question.  The MouseConnectivityApi.download_projection_density function does not have a return value.  All it does is download the file from the API to a given file location.  If you would like to open it, you will need to read it with pynrrd.  The MouseConnectivityCache.get_projection_density function wraps this for you.