# Pycharm: unable to add pycharm.exe

Tags: python, pycharm

I have downloaded PyCharm and I am not able to add the interpreter. I have referred all the topics here, and was able to find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32832062/pycharm-doesnt-detect-interpreter/32832234). But still I couldn't solve the problem, when I select the PyCharm.exe file it says "The selected file is not a valid home for Python SDK". I have rebooted my system, Uninstalled and reinstalled PyCharm, but did not find any luck. Please Help!

Comment: Make sure the path to python provided in pycharm is correct

Comment: You are looking for a "python.exe" not "PyCharm.exe"

Comment: Okay, I'm just a novice here in Python. Can you clear my doubt. Previously, when I installed Python, It made me select the interpreter Python.exe. So, I am assuming that for PyCharm the interpreter would be the same executable file, and that is what I have read in the topics I came across till now, I could be wrong, but does this mean that along with PyCharm I'll need to install Python as well? To add the interpreter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `pycharm`,

select `create new project` and then you will get to name the project and select the project interpreter. In the `Location` you need to name and path for the project.

There will be `project Interpreter` just below `Location`. There you need to select `New environment` and provide the respective values. Make sure in the `Base Interpreter` selects the `python.exe`