# How to set PYTHONPATH to multiple folders

Tags: python, bash

In `~/.bash_profile` file (OS X) I've set PYTHONPATH to point to two folders:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Applications/python/common:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=/Applications/sitecustomize:$PYTHONPATH
```

Even while `sitecustomize` folder is set on a second line (after `/common`) 
the first path is ignored and I am not able to import any module from the path defined in a first line. What needs to be revised in above syntax to make both folders PYTHONPATHish to Python?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Append your paths so there is only one PYTHONPATH.

```
PYTHONPATH="/Applications/python/common:/Applications/sitecustomize:$PYTHONPATH"
export PYTHONPATH
```

Then `source ~/.bash_profile`

OR import them into your Python script (this would only work for the script added to):

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/Applications/python/common")
sys.path.append("/Applications/sitecustomize")
```

Comment: If on the Windows platform, use a ; character to separate modules in this environment variable instead of a : character for the Linux platform.