# Python ModuleNotFound issue in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have an issue with importing modules from a subfolder in my projects main folder.

The project structure is:

```
project_folder/
|-- main.py
|
|-- tools/
    |-- script.py
|
|-- utils/
    |--__init__.py
    |--misc.py
```

When I try to import a function from the `utils.misc` module, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError` (using VSCode), but I can run the code with no issue when I use Spyder.

The statement I use in *script.py* to import is:

```py
from utils.misc import my_function
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Please see a snapshot of the error below:

[image]

I have also added `${workpsaceFolder}` to `cwd` configuration, and added the project root folder to the `PYTHONPATH` in the `launch.json` file (see below). However the `project_folder` still fails to show up when I print `sys.path`.

[image]

UPDATE:
See the screenshot of the project structure and the error below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you changed the `cwd`([official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_cwd)) configuration in the launch.json file? It defaults `to ${workspaceFolder}`. Then the import you take should work.

**Update**:

```
{
      "name": "Python: Current File",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "env": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"
      },
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
}
```

Add the `env` configuration.

**Update**

```
  "env": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"
  },
```

will not work when you use `Code Runner`.

**Update:**
You need to run the code with `terminal`(**F5**) instead of `Code Runner`. Or like this:

[image]

And make sure save the file before you run the code.

UPDATE:
See the screenshot of the project structure and the error below

[image]

Comment: The `cwd` is set to the `${workspaceFolder}`, which is my project's root directory, but it's still unable to locate the module.

Comment: Can you navigate to misc in 'from utils.misc import my_function', with 'F12' or 'ctrl+click'? And can you run it successfully? If possible, can you provide a picture about it?

Comment: It does run successfully. Seems like I'm not able to attach a photo in the comments.

Comment: Can you update the question to attach a photo? It looks like a problem with the linting. You should check what prompts the error. If it the language Server, try to switch to another one the same goes for the linter you are using.

Comment: Does it work in the normal terminal instead of code runner?

Comment: Added the `env` configuration as well, still not working unfortunately

Comment: Can you add 'print(sys.path)' to check the locations of the interpreter search for modules(https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?highlight=sys%20path#sys.path)? Make sure the parent folder of 'utils' was in it.

Comment: If the parent folder of 'utils' was not in it, add it to the 'PYTHONPATH' under the 'env' configuration. For example: ${workspaceFolder}/project_folder;${workspaceFolder}

Comment: Thanks again for the help, I did what you suggested but still not getting it to run. Please see the edited question above to see the changes I've made.

Comment: Sorry for the late, could you have a look at the update?

Comment: If you directly add 'import sys

sys.path.append("g:\\projects\\project_folder")', before 'from utils.misc import my_function'. It works or not?

Comment: it works when I add it manually to sys.path, but is there a way I can get around doing that? thanks again

Comment: Sorry for the late. How do you run it with terminal?  F5? As you have configured the 'PYTHONPATH' under the 'env' configuration. You should get it with no problem.Please have a look at the update.

Comment: running in terminal doesn't work unless I add the path manually to sys.path

Comment: Can you add ${workspaceFolder} in the PYTHONPATH? and provide the screenshot of the terminal? remember add  ';' after project_folder.

Comment: If you can provide a screenshot of the project struct, it will be great.

Comment: Please see the update, added a screenshot in the question (also I added the screenshot to your answer by mistake, but can't delete it!)

Comment: You could not run it like this. You should run it through 'F5', otherwise, the configurations in the launch.json will not work.

Comment: Thanks it works using F5, so it can only be run in debug mode?

Comment: Yes, it is. Otherwise, you need to configure the 'sys.path' in other ways, such as 'sys.path.append' we have talked about.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `.env` file in the root of your working directory (`real_root_dir` in my case)

- Opened in VSCode folder is `real_root_dir`
- Project tree is

```
real_root_dir
├── .env
├── other_project
│   └── c.py
└── project_root
    ├── a.py
    ├── b
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── b.py
    └── run.py
```

- content of `.env` file is

```
PYTHONPATH=project_root:other_project
```

- `run.py` code

```
from a import A
from b.b import B
from c import C

print(A)
print(B)
print(C)
```

With this configuration VSCode will find even `C` and allow to jump into it, but python still don't know about `C`, so running output will be:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sergei/temp/real_root_dir/project_root/run.py", line 3, in <module>
    from c import C
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'c'
```

Of course, importing of outside `C` module is not normal in usual cases.
But `A` and `B` will work properly with python interpreter and VSCode both.

Comment: Could you clarify how I should add the  `.env` configuration? Should I add it to the `launch.json` file or is there another way I should do it?

Comment: @NIM4 Sorry for lacks in explanation. `.env` is just a file. I updated project tree, so now you can check where you need to place it

Comment: I attempted this and it's not working unfortunately. In `PYTHONPATH=project_root:other_project`, are `project_root` and `other_project` full directories? also what does the `:` represent? thanks for the help

Comment: `:` is a directory separator. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39682688/how-to-set-pythonpath-to-multiple-folders
`project_root` and `other_project` are relative paths that relate on `real_root_dir`

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to solve the issue