# Test an examples directory for a Python project

Tags: python, pytest

I have a project for developing a Python package where the structure of the project is similar to the following:

```
myproject/
├── README.md
├── examples/
│   ├── ex1.py
│   └── ex2.py
├── pyproject.toml
├── src/
│    └── mypackage/
│        ├── __init__.py
│        ├── adder.py
│        └── divider.py
└── tests/
    ├── test_adder.py
    ├── test_divider.py
    └── test_examples.py
```

The project is for developing a Python package named `mypackage` which is located in the `src` directory. The package is uploaded to PyPI where users can `pip install` it. Tests for the package are run with pytest and are located in the `tests` directory. Examples of using the package are in the `examples` directory. The examples are just scripts as shown below for `ex1.py`

```py
"""
Example 1
"""
from mypackage import adder

x = 2.5
y = 8
a = adder(x, y)

print('a is', a)
```

The purpose of `test_examples.py` is to test the example files, its contents are shown below:

```py
from examples import ex1
from examples import ex2

def test_ex1():
    ex1

def test_ex2():
    ex2
```

When I run pytest in the `myproject` directory I get the error shown here:

```
$ cd myproject
$ pytest

platform darwin -- Python 3.10.6, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /Users/gavinw/Desktop/test-examples
collected 2 items / 1 error

================================================================== ERRORS ==================================================================
_________________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_examples.py __________________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/gavinw/Desktop/test-examples/tests/test_examples.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/opt/miniconda3/envs/ztest/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/test_examples.py:1: in <module>
    from examples import ex1
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'examples'
========================================================= short test summary info ==========================================================
ERROR tests/test_examples.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
============================================================= 1 error in 0.05s =============================================================
```

It looks like pytest is not able to run the files in the examples directory because the location does not allow them to be imported. Any suggestions on how I can test the example files? Should I even use pytest for testing examples or is there a different testing tool for this?

Comment: I think that you should put the examples under the tests directory, so they can be imported properly.

Comment: @PeterK The purpose of the examples is to demonstrate how to use the package. I would like to keep them separate from the tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches that fix the problem. The first approach is to run pytest using the following command:

```
python -m pytest
```

The second approach is to add the project directory in the `pyproject.toml` file using the `pythonpath` setting as shown below. Then just use the `pytest` command to run the tests.

```ini
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
pythonpath = ["."]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure that the examples directory contains `__init__.py` so it can be imported correctly.

If that is not enough, you can use `PYTHONPATH`:

`PYTHONPATH="/path/to/your/code/project/:/path/to/your/code/project/examples"  pytest`

`PYTHONPATH` might be tricky, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4580120/3800552 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/39682723/3800552 for some usage examples.

Comment: Why would I set the PYTHONPATH like this instead of using the pythonpath in the pytest configuration settings? Documentation for this is found [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html?highlight=pythonpath#confval-pythonpath).

Comment: No particular reason. My main bet is the missing `__init__.py` file - that should do the trick for you.

Comment: If I run `python -m pytest` then everything works fine. There's no need to add an `__init__.py` in the examples directory.