# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'memoize'

Tags: python, module, pytest

I tried this,

```
pip install memoize
Requirement already satisfied: memoize
```

But every time i run pytest, I get the above error 
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'memoize'`
and it fails to load the `conftest.py` file even though it is in my tests folder and it also contains an `__init__.py` file.

any suggestions what else could be wrong/missing?

Comment: Could be because of the python path issue have you tried *python -m pytest projectrootdir/*

Comment: This worked. Thanks @NareshKumar

Comment: what does the -m stand for? I have issues with pylint as well...`unable to import memoize (import-error)`

Comment: you can check `python --help` for more details on arguments. The issue is with the path variables you might be having different version python/modules and your root project folder is not in the `sys.path` for python to process it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python path could be the issue

`python -m pytest projectroot`/

To fix this you could also set the path using

```
import sys, os
myPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) 
sys.path.insert(0, myPath + '/../')
```

By @Not_a_golfer

Comment: The above command helped pytest work. but linter raises this `Unable to import 'memoize' (import-error)` any idea how to avoid this. I tried uninstalling the global version, and installing `memoize` again. didn't help

Comment: Could you provide your project tree structure? You can also check the following doc [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) . To check your current path [Finding-current-path-used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489599/how-do-i-find-out-my-python-path-using-python)