# Can't import plotly.express in .py script despite being installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, plotly, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Before this gets marked as duplicate, I've been wrestling with this for quite some time and have tried all the troubleshooting options I have found online. Hopefully someone out there knows what's going on.

When I try to do the plotly.express import it fails with the following error:

```
File "/mnt/e/Backup/facebook/plotly.py", line 2, in <module>
    import plotly.express as px
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly.express'; 'plotly' is not a package
```

If I try `import plotly` I get no errors however am not able to use plotly.express.

The fixes I've seen for the error all point to plotly not being installed and to do so via pip.
Running `pip3 list` shows that plotly is installed.

```
ahren@AhrBeast:~$ pip3 list | grep plotly
plotly                 4.11.0              
plotly-express         0.4.1
```

Importing plotly.express from the terminal works fine:

```
ahren@AhrBeast:~$ python3
Python 3.8.2 (default, Jul 16 2020, 14:00:26) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
>>> import plotly.express as px
>>> px.data.iris()
     sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width    species  species_id
0             5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2     setosa           1
1             4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2     setosa           1
...
```

Since plotly.express works from the terminal I thought maybe VSCode was running my code in a different environment than the termial but that seems to not be the case.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

results in: `/usr/bin/python3`
and so does the same thing from the terminal

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.executable)
/usr/bin/python3
```

Last I tried setting up a Jupyter notebook and got plotly.express working there (different environment on Windows via Anaoconda), but need to be able to use plotly natively within my .py scripts intstead of in a notebook.

I'm not sure what else to try at this point so if anyone has any pointers that'd be most appreciated.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Could you also check your path? That might be different. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489599/how-do-i-find-out-my-python-path-using-python

Comment: try to list the installed packages programmatically `from pip import _internal
_internal.main(['list'])`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your script is named `plotly.py`. When you run the script Python adds its directory to `sys.path` so `import plotly` imports the script. No error reported but it imports a wrong `plotly`.

`import plotly.express` searches `sys.path` for `plotly`, finds the script, tries to import `plotly.express` and fails.

The bottom line: rename the script and remember to never name your scripts the same names that shadow existing modules and packages. Never name your scripts `email.py` or `test.py`, for example.

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick. I had done a save as initially and it didn't work but then deleting the plotly.py file made it work - which makes sense. It will definitely stick with me not to name my script the same as a module name. Thanks again.

Comment: Wow...been chasing this import error for an hour. This was it for me as well.

Comment: I made this mistake as well. Renaming the script solved the issue.