# Does somebody know how to Install Pandas on R? Without getting the error unexpected symbol in "import pandas"

Tags: python, r, pandas, reticulate

I am trying to use pandas on my RStudio
2022.07.1 Build 554
© 2009-2022 RStudio, PBC
"Spotted Wakerobin" Release (7872775e, 2022-07-22) for Windows
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.8 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36

What did I do?

- Installed reticulated
- Installed pandas
  Also Ran Commands on my RStudio -> Markdown and directly in the RConsole:
  library(reticulate)
  py_install("pandas")

When I try to use pandas:
Error: unexpected symbol in "import pandas"

Error:

```
> py_install("pandas")
Using virtual environment "~/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate" ...
+ "C:/Users/darre/OneDrive/Dokumente/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/Scripts/python.exe" -m pip install --upgrade --no-user "pandas"
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\darre\onedrive\dokumente\.virtualenvs\r-reticulate\lib\site-packages (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.1 in c:\users\darre\onedrive\dokumente\.virtualenvs\r-reticulate\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in c:\users\darre\onedrive\dokumente\.virtualenvs\r-reticulate\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2022.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21.0 in c:\users\darre\onedrive\dokumente\.virtualenvs\r-reticulate\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.23.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\darre\onedrive\dokumente\.virtualenvs\r-reticulate\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.1->pandas) (1.16.0)
> py_install("pandas")
Using virtual environment "~/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate" ...
+ "C:/Users/darre/OneDrive/Dokumente/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/Scripts/python.exe" -m pip install --upgrade --no-user "pandas"
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\darre\onedrive\dokumente\.virtualenvs\r-reticulate\lib\site-packages (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21.0 in c:\users\darre\onedrive\dokumente\.virtualenvs\r-reticulate\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.23.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in c:\users\darre\onedrive\dokumente\.virtualenvs\r-reticulate\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2022.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.1 in c:\users\darre\onedrive\dokumente\.virtualenvs\r-reticulate\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\darre\onedrive\dokumente\.virtualenvs\r-reticulate\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.1->pandas) (1.16.0)
> import pandas as pd
Error: unexpected symbol in "import pandas"
```

Comment: https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/ You should use the `import()` function, or source a python script with `source_python`. It is trying to recognize the import pandas as pd as an R script

Comment: I just tried it now, I get still an error

Warning message:
Paket ‘reticulate’ wurde unter R Version 4.1.3 erstellt 
> use_python("/usr/local/bin/python")
Error in use_python("/usr/local/bin/python") : 
  Specified version of python '/usr/local/bin/python' does not exist.
> os <- import("pandas")
Error in py_module_import(module, convert = convert) : 
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
> import pandas
Error: unexpected symbol in "import pandas"
> import pandas as pd
Error: unexpected symbol in "import pandas"

Comment: You need to find the correct Python path it appears, it may not be at that exact path. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489599/how-do-i-find-out-my-pythonpath-using-python

Answer (score 0):

R doesn't know what `import pandas as pd` means.  That's python syntax.

You want:

```
pd <- import("pandas")
```