# Trouble importing libraries

Tags: python, python-import

I am having issues when I try to import requests and beautifulsoup into my script. I have created a virtual environment in this path: C:\Users\eldet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\venv and have installed the two libraries here: C:\Users\eldet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\venv\Lib\site-packages while my script is here: C:\Users\eldet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\venv\Scripts. The IDE I am using is VSCode. As far as I have understood (I’m new to Python), the libraries should import, since they are in the same virtual environment. The Python interpreter is in the sys.path: C:\Users\eldet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311, the requests version is 2.31.0, bs4 is 0.0.1 and beautigulsoup4, 4.12.2. When debugging, I get the Module not found error.

This is the script:

```
def main():
    """This is the main function of the program.

    It imports the `requests` and `bs4` modules and then uses them to scrape data from Google Maps.

    The `get_restaurants()` function is used to get a list of restaurants from Google Maps.
    The `print()` function is used to print the list of restaurants.
    """

    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests

    def get_restaurants(query):
        """Gets a list of restaurants from Google Maps.

        Args:
            query: The query to search for.

        Returns:
            A list of restaurant objects. Each restaurant object has the following properties:
                name: The name of the restaurant.
                address: The address of the restaurant.
                phone_number: The phone number of the restaurant.
                website: The website of the restaurant.
                rating: The rating of the restaurant.
                reviews: The number of reviews for the restaurant.
        """

        url = "https://www.google.com/maps/search/{}/@37.9716578,23.7168783,12z".format(query)
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

        restaurants = []
        for restaurant in soup.find_all("div", class_="section-result"):
            try:
                name = restaurant.find("div", class_="section-result__title").text.strip()
            except AttributeError:
                name = None
            try:
                address = restaurant.find("div", class_="section-result__address").text.strip()
            except AttributeError:
                address = None
            try:
                phone_number = restaurant.find("div", class_="section-result__phone").text.strip()
            except AttributeError:
                phone_number = None
            try:
                website = restaurant.find("div", class_="section-result__website").text.strip()
            except AttributeError:
                website = None
            try:
                rating = restaurant.find("div", class_="section-result__rating").text.strip()
            except AttributeError:
                rating = None
            try:
                reviews = restaurant.find("div", class_="section-result__reviews").text.strip()
            except AttributeError:
                reviews = None

            restaurants.append({
                "name": name,
                "address": address,
                "phone_number": phone_number,
                "website": website,
                "rating": rating,
                "reviews": reviews,
            })

        return restaurants

    query = "Mexican restaurants in Athens, Greece"
    restaurants = get_restaurants(query)

    for restaurant in restaurants:
        print(restaurant)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

- I have uninstalled and reinstalled the libraries as well as started all over with the installation of Python.
- I have set the path to include ther intrpreter running the following:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python311.
```

- I have made sure that the directory is in the path by running:

```
echo %PATH%
```

Paths found:

```
C:\Users\eldet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\venv\Lib\site-packages>echo %PATH%
C:\Users\eldet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\venv\Scripts;C:\Users\eldet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\;C:\Users\eldet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\;C:\Users\eldet\mongosh-1.6.0-win32-x64\mongosh-1.6.0-win32-x64\bin;C:\Python310\Scripts\;C:\Python310\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Users\eldet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\pip.exe;C:\users\eldet\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages;C:\Users\eldet\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\eldet\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\eldet\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MongoDB Atlas CLI\;C:\Users\eldet\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\eldet\Documents\Selenium Scraper
```

- I have activated the virtual environment and made surre that all installations are within it:

```
(venv) C:\Users\eldet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\venv\Lib\site-packages
```

- This is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\eldet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\venv\Scripts\google_maps_scraper.py", line 78, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\eldet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\venv\Scripts\google_maps_scraper.py", line 10, in main
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

- Last but not least, I have restarted my computer.

So, this is how things stand at this moment. I don't understand:

```
(maps_scraper) C:\Users\eldet\maps_scraper\Lib\site-packages>dir
 Volume in drive C is Windows-SSD
 Volume Serial Number is D2DD-4186

 Directory of C:\Users\eldet\maps_scraper\Lib\site-packages

25/06/2023  09:37    <DIR>          .
22/06/2023  08:32    <DIR>          ..
22/06/2023  08:36    <DIR>          beautifulsoup4-4.12.2.dist-info
22/06/2023  08:36    <DIR>          bs4
24/06/2023  12:27    <DIR>          bs4-0.0.1.dist-info
22/06/2023  08:34    <DIR>          certifi
22/06/2023  08:34    <DIR>          certifi-2023.5.7.dist-info
24/06/2023  22:33    <DIR>          cffi
24/06/2023  22:33    <DIR>          cffi-1.15.1.dist-info
22/06/2023  08:34    <DIR>          charset_normalizer
22/06/2023  08:34    <DIR>          charset_normalizer-3.1.0.dist-info
22/06/2023  08:32               151 distutils-precedence.pth
24/06/2023  22:33    <DIR>          file
24/06/2023  22:33    <DIR>          file-0.3.0.dist-info
24/06/2023  21:51             2,596 google_maps_scraper.py
22/06/2023  08:34    <DIR>          idna
22/06/2023  08:34    <DIR>          idna-3.4.dist-info
22/06/2023  08:32    <DIR>          pip
22/06/2023  08:32    <DIR>          pip-23.1.2.dist-info
22/06/2023  08:32    <DIR>          pkg_resources
24/06/2023  22:33    <DIR>          pycparser
24/06/2023  22:33    <DIR>          pycparser-2.21.dist-info
24/06/2023  23:14    <DIR>          pyflakes
24/06/2023  23:14    <DIR>          pyflakes-3.0.1.dist-info
24/06/2023  12:26    <DIR>          requests
24/06/2023  12:26    <DIR>          requests-2.31.0.dist-info
22/06/2023  08:32    <DIR>          setuptools
22/06/2023  08:32    <DIR>          setuptools-65.5.0.dist-info
25/06/2023  09:52               311 set_pythonpath.py
22/06/2023  08:36    <DIR>          soupsieve
22/06/2023  08:36    <DIR>          soupsieve-2.4.1.dist-info
22/06/2023  08:34    <DIR>          urllib3
22/06/2023  08:34    <DIR>          urllib3-2.0.3.dist-info
24/06/2023  22:33           181,760 _cffi_backend.cp311-win_amd64.pyd
22/06/2023  08:32    <DIR>          _distutils_hack
24/06/2023  22:07    <DIR>          __pycache__
               4 File(s)        184,818 bytes
              32 Dir(s)  844,945,043,456 bytes free
```

Answer (score 2):

You have created your app *within* a virtual environment and installed the relevant modules (here: requests, bs4) within that environment.

You'll also have to run the script from *within* the activated virtual environment, because the modules are not present in your global python packages.
*(unless you install them there or add to pythonpath, which defeats the purpose of your virtual environment).*

The VSCode [documentation on virtual environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) says you'll can select the correct interpreter (the python of your virtual environment, that is) by using **Python: Select Interpreter** or **Ctrl+Shift+P** to bring up the available/defined options.

Comment: Thanks! I have been running the script from within the virtual environment and have correctly selected the interpreter.

Comment: Here's what I have done, but to no avail:


    I have left the python interpreter in C:\Users\eldet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311 and have deleted venv to get out of the virtual environment?

    I have moved my script to C:\Users\eldet\Documents\Python Scripts\Web Scraping

    I have created a new virtual environment here: C:\Users\eldet\Documents\python_virtual_environments and have installed the libraries.

    I have activated the virtual environment and then I have run the script but I still get a ModuleNotFoundError.

Comment: Try this. Activate your virtual environment, then find out your pythonpath from within that, using the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489599/how-do-i-find-out-my-pythonpath-using-python -- then confirm the modules are actually in there. (You could also temporarily install bs4/requests for your system-wide python and try if your script runs there).